# Does a NSURLConnection retain its delegate?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, memory-management

Summary of my question: Does NSURLConnection retain its delegate?

Detailed question and scenario:

I have a custom class, called JsonDownloader that is takes in a URL and returns an NSDictionary of the JSON that the URL returns.

On an iPhone app, I do something like this. (the init method kicks off the whole process)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    JsonDownloder *temp = [[[JsonDownloader alloc] initWithURL:urlString returnDataTo:self]];
    [temp release];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

When the JsonDownloader is done downloading and parsing, it performs a callback to the returnDataTo: object, in this case, the calling object.

This works just fine. Even if I introduce a 30 second delay in my web servers response, the JsonDownloader still exists and does it's callback correctly.

So my questions is this: What is keeping JsonDownloader way past the end of the event cycle? I am explicitly releasing it.

My hunch is that NSURLConnection must do a retain on its delegate, but I didn't see anything in the documentation. Anyone have an ideas?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There aren't many setters that don't either copy or retain a variable being passed to it, lest the memory of said variable be re-allocated to something else when its retain count reaches zero.

However, the answer is YES, it does.  A little bit of test code shows the delegate's retain count go up:

```
NSLog(@"Retain count before: %d", [self retainCount]);
NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"]];
NSURLConnection* conn = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
NSLog(@"Retain count after: %d", [self retainCount]);
```

which produces in the log:

```
Running…
2009-07-09 02:13:40.516 delegateRetain[45123:a0f] Retain count before: 1
2009-07-09 02:13:40.525 delegateRetain[45123:a0f] Retain count after: 2

Debugger stopped.
```

So you can see pretty clearly that in `connectionWithRequest:delegate:` "self" is indeed having its retain count increased +1.  If you're feeling brave and want to mess with the EXC_BAD_ACCESS gods, add in

```
[conn dealloc];
NSLog(@"Retain count after dealloc: %d", [self retainCount]);
```

which will print out "1" again, showing a post dealloc decrement.  However, you'll get a nice `Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.` because the `NSAutoreleasePool` will try to release the connection and it will be gone ;)

Comment: Great question and great answer. I was struggling with this myself, but I decided to add [self release] right after the delegate assigning to even out the retain count. Since self is delegate in my class, I saw no reason for its retain count to be increased. If that's incorrect, someone let me know.

Comment: I just want to add - thank you. The Missing Manual, part 327. It beggars belief that this kinda sorta important fact is not mentioned in the Apple documentation. I figured it was retaining it but wasn't sure, the docs say nothing about it, and in many if not most cases delegates in Cocoa frameworks are *not* retained. This is the exception.

Answer (score 9):

Most delegate **properties** are not retained but assigned to prevent circular references. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918698/why-are-objective-c-delegates-usually-given-the-property-assign-instead-of-retain) question about that as well.

However, NSUrlConnection does not have a specific delegate property. You have to specify the delegate along with the initialization of the connection. I think that is why it does receive a retain, as Dave Martorana showed.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, "The connection retains delegate. It releases delegate when the connection finishes loading, fails, or is canceled," according to the [Xcode Documentation for `-[NSURLConnection initWithRequest:delegate:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) under Special Considerations. See also: [NSURLConnection inherent memory leak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222687/nsurlconnection-inherent-memory-leak/6222689#6222689)

Comment: Ok so this is a "Note" on NSURLConnection. Still it should be mentioned in the method description since it's rather important.