# NSURLConnection inherent memory leak?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-leaks, nsurlconnection

In the example in the [Xcode Documentation : URL Loading System Programming Guide : Using NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html), they `alloc` an `NSURLConnection` (`theConnection`) and then release it in the callbacks: `-connection:didFailWithError:` & `-connectionDidFinishLoading:`. But, won't `theConnection` leak (i.e. never get released) if the delegate is released before either of the callback methods get called?

Answer (score 4):

No, `theConnection` won't leak because, as the [Xcode Documentation for `-[NSURLConnection initWithRequest:delegate:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) states under Special Considerations: "The connection retains delegate. It releases delegate when the connection finishes loading, fails, or is canceled."