# How to release attribute which is protocol?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, protocols

I have working for iPhone development for a while. First time, I so surprised with memory-management in objective-c :). but now I got it a little bit.

The question is, sometime, I use protocol as an attribute of a class, because I think its definition very similar to 'interface' in C# or Java. like below.

```
@protocol Shield
   ...
@end

// Interface
@interface Dragon {
    id<Shield> shield
    NSString * name;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) id<Shield> shield;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString * name;

@end
```

but I alway release any attribute object in dealloc() method. like below.

```
-(void)dealloc {
   [name release];
   [shield release];  // <--- Totally impossible. xcode said '-release not found in protocol'
   [super dealloc];
 }
```

As you see, I couldn't release the protocol. So would this cause me future memory issue? Do you have another way to handle this solution to advice me?

Comment: iKenndac's answer below is the proper way. Alternatively, you can cast the ID to an NSObject protocol conform ID and call the release method. `[(id<NSObject)shield release]` or to an NSObject `[(NSObject*)shield release]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to define your protocol as adhering to the `NSObject` protocol, like this:

```
@protocol Shield <NSObject>
   ...
@end
```

It's simple when you know how! ;-)

Edit: Also, you're correct - protocols in Objective-C are equivalent to interfaces in Java and C#.

Another edit: It might strike you as odd having to do this, but Objective-C allows for multiple root objects, so you can't actually guarantee that every object will descend from `NSObject`. Since `release` is an `NSObject` method, you have to define your protocol as also adhering to the `<NSObject>` protocol before you can be sure it'll be able to respond to the `release` method.

Answer (score 1):

1-the proper thing to do instead of [shield release] is setting

```
self.shield = nil;
```

2-Also change

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) id<Shield> shield;
```

to

```
@property (nonatomic,assign) id<Shield> shield;
```

Then you are fine.

edit:

> The reason that you avoid retaining
>   delegates is that you need to avoid a
>   retain loop:
>
> A creates B A sets itself as B's
>   delegate … A is released by its owner
>
> If B had retained A, A wouldn't be
>   released, as B owns A, thus A's
>   dealloc would never get called,
>   causing both A and B to leak.
>
> You shouldn't worry about A going away
>   b/c it owns B and thus gets rid of it
>   in dealloc.

[Why are Objective-C delegates usually given the property assign instead of retain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918698/why-are-objective-c-delegates-usually-given-the-property-assign-instead-of-retain)

please see uitableview class reference for an example protocol declaration:

@property(nonatomic, assign) id < UITableViewDelegate> delegate

Comment: There's nothing wrong in releasing member directly. And changing property attribute to assign you either get a memory leak (if shield was retained) or an error at run-time (if you just assign to shield an autoreleased object)

Comment: hmm so whenever someone uses uitableviews they get errors at run time. i see now. please see
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: OK sorry, I didn't see anything about delegates in original question though. Its hard to talk about attributes without knowing their actual usage

Comment: a delegate is a symbolic common name used for structures like this:

@protocol Shield
   ...
@end

the OP tries to release its delegate(i.e shield), and its just wrong for the aforementioned reasons.