# when to use respondsToSelector in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios

```
- (void)someMethod
{
    if ( [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(operationShouldProceed)] )
    {
        if ( [delegate operationShouldProceed] )
        {
            // do something appropriate
        }
    }
}
```

The [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH7-SW29) says:

> The precaution is necessary only for optional methods in a formal protocol or methods of an informal protocol

What does it mean? If I use a formal protocol I can just use `[delegate myMethod]`?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You use it pretty much just when you think you need to: to check to see if an object implements the method you are about to call. *Usually* this is done when you have an optional methods or an informal protocol.

I've only ever used `respondsToSelector` when I'm writing code that must communicate with a delegate object.

```
if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(engineDidStartRunning:)]) {
        [self.delegate engineDidStartRunning:self];
    }
```

You sometimes would want to use `respondsToSelector` on any method that returns and `id` or generic `NSObject` where you aren't sure what the class of the returned object is.

Comment: thanks. I understand now. I noticed you use self.delegate, which is a property. I just use an instance variable: id delegate. what's the difference? Im learning objective-c. thanks again

Comment: `self.delegate` is exactly the same as calling `[self delegate]`. In my code there's no difference between `[self.delegate someMethod]` and `[_delegate someMethod]`, but I tend to use dot syntax because it keeps it straight in my mind which variables are local to the method I'm in and which are instance variables.

Comment: If you're just starting, it will be worth your time to read Apple's guide to Obj-C. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17

Comment: one more question: do i need to set delegate = nil in the dealloc and viewDidUnload method?(of the delegate class or the class that implements the delegate or neither?)

Comment: No. Delegate properties should almost always be assigned instead of retained. In the vast majority of examples, you don't own the delegate object, so you shouldn't retain or release it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918698/why-are-objective-c-delegates-usually-given-the-property-assign-instead-of-retain/918732#918732

Comment: It is basically syntatic sugar, but when I have a very regular set of delegate methods I'm using, a preprocessor macro can really make the code more readable. For example:
#define NOTIFY_OPTIONAL(sel, id) if ([id respondsToSelector:@selector(sel)]) {[id sel self];}

Then in my code:
    NOTIFY_OPTIONAL(playStarted:, _focusPlayer);

Comment: I am using a delegate in similar fashion:

if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(engineDidStartRunning:)]) {
        [self.delegate engineDidStartRunning:self];
    }


But it still sometimes gives me an error 
Bad Excess.

Answer (score 47):

Just to add to what @kubi said, another time I use it is when a method was added to a pre-existing class in a newer version of the frameworks, but I still need to be backwards-compatible.  For example:

```
if ([myObject respondsToSelector:@selector(doAwesomeNewThing)]) {
  [myObject doAwesomeNewThing];
} else {
  [self doOldWorkaroundHackWithObject:myObject];
}
```

Answer (score 15):

As kubi mentioned `respondsToSelector` is normally used when you have a an instance of a method that conforms to a protocol.

```
// Extend from the NSObject protocol so it is safe to call `respondsToSelector` 
@protocol MyProtocol <NSObject> 

// @required by default
- (void) requiredMethod;

@optional

- (void)optionalMethod;

@end
```

Given and instance of this protocol we can safely call any required method.

```
id <MyProtocol> myObject = ... 
[myObject requiredMethod];
```

However, optional methods may or may not be implemented, so you need to check at runtime.

```
if ([myObject respondsToSelector:@selector(optionalMethod)]) 
{
     [myObject optionalMethod];
}
```

Doing this will prevent a crash with an unrecognised selector.

---

Also, the reason why you should declare protocols as an extension of NSObjects, i.e.

```
@protocol MyProtocol <NSObject>
```

Is because the NSObject protocol declares the [`respondsToSelector:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/respondsToSelector%3a) selector.  Otherwise XCode would think that it is unsafe to call it.

Comment: I just forgot to add <NSObject> solved my problem thanks

Answer (score 3):

Old question, but I have learned to be very cautios with using stuff like addTarget:@selector(fu:) because the method name is not checked nor included in refactoring by XCODE. This has caused me quite some trouble already. So now I made it a habbit to always embed stuff like addTarget or addObserver  in a respondsToSelector-Check like so:

```
if([self respondsToSelector:@selector(buttonClicked:)]){
    [self.button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}else{
    DebugLog(@"Warning - a class or delegate did not respond to selector in class %@", self);
}
```

I know its not super elegant, but i'd rather add some boilerplate code than have an unexpected crash of my apps in the App Store.

Comment: I think "methodName:" is now checked in statements like @selector(methodName:) in xCode now aren't they?

Comment: @Grezzo - XCode will only check that the selector exists somewhere in your target.  So for example if you wrote `@selector(date)` instead of `@selector(data)` XCode will not warn you because the `date` selector exists on `NSDateComponents`.