# How to check introduction of a feature at compile time in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios

If I use a feature which is deprecated at current SDK version, compiler will warn about it.
I'm finding a feature just opposite against it.

If I use a class or method which is not defined in specific SDK version, compiler warn about it.

How can I gain this feature? I tried defining `__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED` by putting definition on prefix-header like this,

```
#undef      __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED
#define     __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED         40000
```

but it catches any of version mismatch even in SDK itself. (such as `UIKit`)

I'm making library code needs backward compatibility for iOS 4.0, and I want some automated method to check backward compatibility. I know feature availability test won't solve everything, but this will make the work a lot easier.

How can I check feature availability for specific SDK version with compiler?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for `respondsToSelector`, where you can check to see if a selector exists in the OS you are currently running on.

But if you really want to future-proof your app, you should always go for the newest API defined for the minimum OS version you want to support.

[Here is a related question about 'respondsToSelector' that may help you out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697058/when-to-use-respondstoselector-in-objective-c).

Comment: I'm sorry for unclear question, but what I need was automated backward compatibility test at compile time. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to check for a class (feature) before attemp to use it by using the NSClassFromString.

```
Class myClass = NSClassFromString(@"CLassThatYouWantToUse"); //get the class object
if (myClass != nil)
    {
       // The device will support this class.. so carry on...
     }
else
      {
           // The device doesn't support this class.
       }
```