# Shorter way to get text from an unknown class (id)object

Tags: ios, objective-c, text, uitextfield, uitextview

I have a dictionary of objects which are composed of `UITextfield`, `UITextView` and `UILabel`, they all have the `text` property. Now I need to get that without using an ugly approach, which is also my current code as of now:

```
NSString *text = @"";

if ( [obj isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]] ) {
    text = [(UITextView *)obj text];
}
else if ( [obj isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]] ) {
    text = [(UITextField *)obj text];
}
else if ( [obj isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]] ) {
    text = [(UILabel *)obj text];
}

[array addObject:text];
```

Is there a way to make this shorter?

Comment: to shorten the code, just cast to `id` instead of your specific classes, so you won't need the `ifs` -- you should be 100% sure that your objects are only of the types you mentioned.

Comment: Well yes but I generally don't trust id so I always put extra measures :D

Answer (score 5):

I believe you're looking for [respondsToSelector:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/respondsToSelector:)

All you have to do is conditionally set the variable based on wether or not your object responds to the selector `text`.

```
NSString *text = nil;

if ([obj respondsToSelector:@selector(text)]) {
    text = [obj text];

    if (text) {
        [array addObject:text];
    }
}
```

And as @Hemang points out, you can find more information on when to use `respondsToSelector:` here: [when to use respondsToSelector in objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697058/when-to-use-respondstoselector-in-objective-c)