# how to pass tokenid from one class to other class in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
hi friend i am passing tokenid throw this class to this here is my code how i am passing it wrong for 



-(void)check
{
    //app.journeyList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [self createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded];

    NSString *filePath = [self getWritableDBPath];

    sqlite3 *database;

    if(sqlite3_open([filePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        const char *sqlStatement = "SELECT Username,Password FROM UserInformation where Username=? and Password=?";
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)    {
            sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 1, [txtUserName.text UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 2, [txtPassword.text UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            //NSString *loginname= [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];
            //          NSString *loginPassword = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];




        }
        if(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) != SQLITE_ROW ) {
            NSLog( @"Save Error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database) );
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"UIAlertView" message:@"User is not valid" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
            alert = nil;

            //We have no data in database so send request to webserver.
            //apitest = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
            //if (apitest.internetConnectionStatus != NotReachable)
//          {
//              [self sendRequest];
//          }
        }
        else {

            isUserValid = YES;
            if (isUserValid) {
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"UIAlertView" message:@"Valid User" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alert show];
                [alert release];

            }       
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);        
}



-(IBAction)update:(id)sender
{
    test1  *check = [[test1 alloc]initWithNibName:@"test1" bundle:nil];
    check.tokenapi1=tokenapi;;
    [self presentModalViewController:check animated:YES];
    //[self getStudents];
}















-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response 
{   
    [webData setLength: 0]; 
} 

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data 
{         
    [webData appendData:data]; 

} 

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error 
{     
    [connection release];  
    [webData release]; 

} 

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
{      
    NSString *loginStatus = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes] length:[webData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
    NSLog(@"%@",loginStatus);  


    //this is to perfrom insert opertion on the userinformation table

    NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:webData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 

    NSDictionary *result = [json_string JSONValue];

    tokenapi = [result objectForKey:@"TokenID"];
    NSLog(@"this is token id:%@",tokenapi);
    //
    BOOL errortest = [[result objectForKey:@"isError"] boolValue];
    if(errortest == FALSE)
    {
     values = [result objectForKey:@"Result"];
        NSLog(@"Valid User");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Invalid User");
    }

    NSMutableArray *results = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

     for (int index = 0; index<[values count]; index++) {
     NSMutableDictionary * value = [values objectAtIndex:index];
     Result * result = [[Result alloc] init];
     result.UserID = [value objectForKey:@"UserId"];
     result.FirstName = [value objectForKey:@"FirstName"];
     result.LastName =[value objectForKey:@"LastName"];
     result.Email =[value objectForKey:@"Email"];
     result.ProfileImage =[value objectForKey:@"ProfileImage"];
     result.ThumbnailImage =[value objectForKey:@"ThumbnailImage"];
     result.DeviceInfoId =[value objectForKey:@"DeviceInfoId"];
     NSLog(@"%@",result.UserID);
         ID=result.UserID;
      NSLog(@"%@",ID);
     [results addObject:result];
     [result release]; 
     }



     for (int index = 0; index<[results count]; index++) {
     Result * result = [results objectAtIndex:index];
     //save the object variables to database here


     [self createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded];

     NSString *filePath = [self getWritableDBPath];

     sqlite3 *database;
     //NSTimeInterval timeStamp = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]; 
//   NSNumber *timeStampObj = [NSNumber numberWithInt: timeStamp];
//   NSLog(@"%@",timeStampObj);
//   NSString *journeyid = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%@_%@", result.UserID, result.DeviceInfoId, timeStampObj];
     if(sqlite3_open([filePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
     const char *sqlStatement = "insert into UserInformation(UserID,DeviceId,Username,Password,FirstName,Email) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
     sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
     if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)    {
     //sqlite3_bind_text( compiledStatement, 1, [journeyid UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
     sqlite3_bind_text( compiledStatement, 1, [result.UserID UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
     sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 2, [result.DeviceInfoId UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
     sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 3, [txtUserName.text UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
     sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 4, [txtPassword.text UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
     sqlite3_bind_text (compiledStatement, 5, [result.FirstName UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
     sqlite3_bind_text (compiledStatement, 6, [result.Email UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

     }
     if(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) != SQLITE_DONE ) {
     NSLog( @"Save Error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database) );
     }
     else {
     UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"UIAlertView" message:@"Record added" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
     [alert show];
     [alert release];
     alert = nil;
     }

     sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
     }
     sqlite3_close(database);   





     }

    [loginStatus release];           
    [connection release];  
    [webData release]; 
} 


-(IBAction)click:(id)sender
{

    [self sendRequest];
    //this is to select username and password from database.
    [self check];




}




this where i am passing then token id using for updat userprofile with tokinid but it not taken here it show error in console it show tokenid invalid i thing i have to pass user id also for update vale as refrence for tokenid
```

Comment: there are a few ways                                              1.pass has pointer                                                    2 create a global variable                                            3 create a delegate

Comment: @Radu could u explain me in detail how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the Delegate pattern for passing a value from one class to others.

See the below SO post.

[How do I set up a simple delegate to communicate between two view controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168919/how-do-i-set-up-a-simple-delegate-to-communicate-between-two-view-controllers/6169118#6169118)