# How can I push table view row text from first tab item to second tab item's label?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitabbarcontroller, selectedindex

I have a tab bar controller and first tab has a table view. How can I send selected index to sencond tab's label?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to pass some data between view controller classes. This answer of mine may help [How to pass a tableview cell value to another page(uiviewcontroller)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7913606/how-to-pass-a-tableview-cell-value-to-another-pageuiviewcontroller/7913786#7913786)