# passing value in init method

Tags: iphone, ios

I am a new programmer of Iphone Application. I work dynamically not use nib files.
I want to pass values from one view controller to another.

in **firstView.m**

these two values

```
cell.textLabel.text
cell.detailTextLabel.text
```

i want to pass in the **TabBarSearchThirdView** init method..

```
TabBarSearchThirdView *thirdView=[[TabBarSearchThirdView alloc]init];
[myView addSubview:thirdView.view];
```

in **TabBarSearchThirdView.m** file.

```
-(id)init
{
firstVariable=..........
secondVariable=..........
}
```

Hope you understood my question. Give me little code or suggestions if possible
and give me a link of easy and good table view tutorial. If possible

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should declare a new init method like this one

```
- (id)initWithText:(NSString *)aText andDetail:(NSString *)aDetail{
    self = [super init];

    if(self){
        firstVariable  = aText;
        secondVariable = aDetail;
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: @Luca..thanks....your code work fine... only this warning comes... can you suggest me..why warning come------->(Messages without a matching method signature

Answer (score 0):

For passing data between viewcontrollers my answer at the below link will help.
[How to pass a tableview cell value to another page(uiviewcontroller)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7913606/how-to-pass-a-tableview-cell-value-to-another-pageuiviewcontroller/7913786#7913786)

Answer (score 0):

for passing values from 1 controller to another controller, you have to define 2 variables in AppDelegate class, with property and synthesis . example NSstring *firstVariable and NSString *secondVariable and mention its property and synthesis.

and after your code
    TabBarSearchThirdView *thirdView=[[TabBarSearchThirdView alloc]init];

```
 MyAppnameDelegate AppDel = (MyAppnameAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
```

//MyAppnameDelegate is your appdelegete class, so change it by your appDelegate class

```
AppDel.firstVariable =cell.textLabel.text;
AppDel. secondVariable = cell.detailTextLabel.text;
[myView addSubview:thirdView.view];
```

process to access values in Third class is 
In viewDidLoad{
    MyAppnameDelegate AppDel = (MyAppnameAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
//MyAppnameDelegate is your appdelegete class, so change it by your appDelegate class

```
nsstring *accessfirstVariable     =.AppDel.firstVariable
nsstring  *accesssecondVariable  =AppDel. secondVariable
}
```

and use this where ever u like… cheers