# How to access the buttons on the tag from another class in iOS?

Tags: ios, class, button

I have a button:

```
- (UIButton *)subwayABBtn
{
    if (!_subwayABBtn)
    {
        _subwayABBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

        _subwayABBtn.tag = ADRESS_SUBWAY_BTN_TAG;

        [_subwayABBtn setTitle:@"Метро" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [_subwayABBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [self.contentView addSubview:_subwayABBtn];
    }

    return _subwayABBtn;
}
```

How can I change the title of the button with a tag from another class? I need to change the title of the button.

Comment: what is "another class" you normally use `viewWithTag:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need a reference to the other class in your view controller, declare the button in its header file and use the method `-viewWithTage:`

Example:

```
OtherClass *otherClass; // This should be set from previous class and a property in your current class 
UIButton *buttonFromOtherClass = [otherClass viewWithTag:BUTTON_TAG]; 
[buttonFromOtherClass setTitle:@"Метро" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 1):

I didnt get what you meant by another class. If its from your view where button is added, then you can use the below code to get UIButton

```
UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)[self.contentView viewWithTag:ADRESS_SUBWAY_BTN_TAG];
[btn setTitle:@"New title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 1):

use `delegates` and `@protocol` to access parent view controller in ios
[refer tis simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168919/how-do-i-set-up-a-simple-delegate-to-communicate-between-two-view-controllers)

[link1](http://iosdevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html)