# Add objects to an Array from another View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, nsarray

I have a `HomeViewController` which has a tableView populated with the array `tableViewArray` (originally empty). When I tap on a barButton, I segue modally to another View Controller called `OutsideViewController` which has another tableView populated by a different array.

What I would like to do is the following:

When I tap on a row in my `OutsideViewController`, I would like to add the selected string value to the `tableViewArray` so that when I go back to `HomeViewController`, the tableView has that new item listed in the tableView.

So far, this is what I have tried:

In the `-didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method of my `OutsideViewController.m` I have this piece of code:

```
NSString *selectedRow = [outsideArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSMutableArray *temporaryArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:selectedRow];

HomeViewController *homeVC = [[HomeViewController alloc] init];
homeVC.tableViewArray = temporaryArray;
```

That code works but the tableView in `HomeViewController` is still empty when I return. Do I have to reload the tableView data?
Am I doing this right?

This is how I have set up my View Controllers in Storyboard:

```
HomeViewController -(modal segue)-> Navigation Controller --> OutsideViewController
```

Also, the return from OutsideViewController to HomeViewController is done by this line of code:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{ }];
```

Comment: I use a global singleton class that can store things like arrays that need to be accessed from any controller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're doing wrong is you're allocationg a new `HomeViewController`. What I would do is keeep a reference to your `HomeViewController` in your `OutsideViewController`. Here is how.

First, in `OutsideViewController.h`, create a property, like this :

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) HomeViewController *homeVC;
```

Don't forget to add `@class HomeViewController;` in your .h, and `#import "HomeViewController.h"` in your .m

In `HomeViewController`, implement the `prepareForSegue:` method like this (replace *ModalSegueIdentifier* with your segue's identifier) :

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ModalSegueIdentifier"]) {
        OutsideViewController *modalVC = (OutsideViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
        modalVC.homeVC = self;
    }
}
```

Then, in `OutsideViewController.m`, instead of doing :

```
HomeViewController *homeVC = [[HomeViewController alloc] init];
homeVC.tableViewArray = temporaryArray;
```

Do this :

```
_homeVC.tableViewArray = temporaryArray;
```

When you leave your modal VC, your HomeVC will have the correct array. Don't forget to refresh your `UITableView` !

*NB: Of course, there are many other ways, and it's maybe not the best one. But still, it should work.*

Comment: This worked just fine, I just had to modify the line: `OutsideViewController *modalVC = (OutsideViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;` to `OutsideViewController *modalVC = (OutsideViewController*)[segue.destinationViewController topViewController];` because of the Navigation Controller in between views

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this too using delegation. You have to create a protocol in your `OutsideViewController` with a method that is responsible for sending the new object to your `HomeViewController`. Do this in OutsideViewController.h:

```
@protocol OutsideViewDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)OutsideViewController:(OutsideViewController *)controller didAddObject:(NSString *)object;
@end
```

In the implementation file you have to change a little bit the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method:

```
NSString *selectedRow = [outsideArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[self.delegate OutsideViewController:self didAddObject:selectedRow];
```

In your HomeViewController.h you have to make your class conforms to the protocol:

```
@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController <OutsideViewDelegate>
```

After, create a property for the delegate:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <OutsideViewDelegate> delegate;
```

To finish the process, implement the protocol in your HomeViewController.m to receive the new object from the OutsideViewController:

```
- (void)OutsideViewController:(OutsideViewController *)controller didAddObject:(NSString *)object
{
     if (object != nil)
     {
          [self.tableViewArray addObject:object];
     }

     [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

The code above depends of if your `tableViewArray` object is mutable or not. If it's not, you can change the type of the object argument in the protocol method to an inmutable array object and just assign `tableViewArray` to the new array.

**EDIT:**

In the `prepareForSegue:` method don't forget to set the delegate:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"SEGUE_IDENTIFIER"]) {
        OutsideViewController *outsideVC = (OutsideViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        [outsideVC setDelegate:self];
    }
}
```

Comment: If I use delegation, does it matter that I have that Navigation Controller in between Views?

Comment: I think not. If I'm not wrong, delegation works with the viewController that implements the protocol method. It should not affect the other controllers. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure you `alloc`, `init` your `tableViewArray` in `HomeViewController`

Second , In this line

```
HomeViewController *homeVC = [[HomeViewController alloc] init]
```

you are creating a new reference to your `HomeViewController` which is not correct, you need to pass correct reference, possibly creating HomeViewController variable in your  `OutsideViewController`

Even though you correctly do first and second suggestion you will still see an empty tableview because  you dont reload the tableview, somehow you need to fire `[self.tableview reloadData];` method.

That means; you need to learn **Delegate** or **NSNotifications** pattern to communicate between child->parent scenarios

[How do I set up a simple delegate to communicate between two view controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168919/how-do-i-set-up-a-simple-delegate-to-communicate-between-two-view-controllers)

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_nsnotificationcenter/

For your question just create a delegate in your `Outside`;
in your OutsideViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol OutsideDelegate;

@interface{}//bunch of interface stuff

// Declare a property for the delegate
@property (weak) id <OutsideDelegate> delegate;
@end

// Protocol Header
@protocol OutsideDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
- (void)dismissPop:(NSMutableArray *)list;
@end
```

in your OutsideViewController.m

```
@synthesize delegate;


//run delegate method
[delegate dismissPop:temporaryArray];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{ }];
```

in your HomeViewController.h

```
#import "OutsideViewController.h"
@interface OutsideViewController : UITableViewController<OutsideDelegate>
{}
@property (strong, nonatomic) OutsideViewController *pvc;
```

in your HomeViewController.m

```
@synthesize pvc;

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"your segue"]) {
        pvc = [segue destinationViewController];
        [pvc setDelegate:self];
    }
}
// delegate callback function

- (void)dismissPop:(NSMutableArray *)list {

    self.tableViewArray=list;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

**Another Solution Would be**

Change your view stack to this:

```
Navigation Controller --> HomeViewController -(push segue)--> OutsideViewController
```

and apply ***rdurand***'s answer

and add this to your HomeViewController :

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [self.tableview reloadData];
}
```

In this solution since you are just push-pop viewcontrollers in a nabigation stack `viewDidAppear` will be called in HomeViewController  everytime when you pop OutsideViewController.

Comment: If I use delegate, does it matter that I have that Navigation Controller in between Views?

Comment: nope it shouldn't matter,id it doesnt work check `delegate` is set up correctly I havent tested the code, but I have also updated my answer with an extra solution, you need to learn delegate and nsnotification sooner or later though