# Accessing array from different view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, arrays, xcode

I have two classes. First one downloads data images and adds them to array one after another. When it's done with all 16 of them runs action to switch view to the second one. My problem here is how to access the array from first class in second class?

Here is the code:

**first.h**

```
@interface first{
    NSMutableArray *imagesArray;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *imagesArray;
```

(array is synthetized in .m file)

**second.h**

```
#import"second";
#import"first.h"
```

**second.m**

```
-(void) viewdidload {
    first *another = [[another alloc] init];
    label.text =  [NSString stringWithFromat:@"%i",[another.imagesArray count]];
    imageView.image = [another.imagesArray objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

`label` shows 0 and `imageView` shows nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: you can create global array or define same `@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *imagesArray;` in **second.h** and when you push from First to Second then pass that array. so you don't need to alloc first view.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6678097/how-to-pass-an-array-from-one-view-controller-to-another and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15789163/add-objects-to-an-array-from-another-view-controller may help

Answer (score 0):

Please get a good understanding about Object-Oriented Features & Object Communication in Objective-C

Do not create a new instance of `first` class.  This will create a new `first` memory object.

You have to access the existing `imagesArray` class object that created in existing  `first` class.

To do this, declare a `NSMutableArray` property in your `second.m` as `weak` and assign it from `first.m` class while you allocating `second.m`.

**Example:**

```
@interface second {

    NSMutableArray *parentImagesArray;
}

@property(nonatomic, weak)NSMutableArray *parentImagesArray;
```

**first.m**

You will have the similar code in your `first.m` file

```
second *secondView = [[second alloc] init];
secondView.parentImagesArray = self.imagesArray; //assign the weak property.
```

**second.m**

```
label.text =  [NSString stringWithFromat:@"%i",[self.parentImagesArray count]];
imageView.image = parentImagesArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

there is two way to achieve your goal...

1) FIRST (pass array from first Controller to Second Controller)

make array object in second controller.h
   then

from first controller where you present second controller

```
second.array_object = first.array_name;
```

In this way you got the array in second controller...

2) declare array as globle

```
Declare array before import statement.
in first.h file

NSMutableArray *arr1;
#import<UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

now whenever and wherever you want to use this array import .h file in which you declare this array and use it directly without creating any objects...

hope this helps you...