# Setting up a delegate to determine a login sequence has completed

Tags: ios, ios5, uiviewcontroller, delegates, uiapplicationdelegate

I am trying to follow this question to setup a delegate for a login sequence:- [How do I set up a simple delegate to communicate between two view controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168919/how-do-i-set-up-a-simple-delegate-to-communicate-between-two-view-controllers)

In my application I have a Main View (MESHomeViewController).
I also have a login structure as follows:

1. MESLoginNavController
2. With a root view controller of MESWelcomeViewController
3. There are also MESLoginViewController and MESSignupViewControllers which can be pushed to the stack.

My aim is to have a delegate method which is only called when the user logs in. I am using a delegate as I cannot use viewDidLoad as the view is often reloaded/shown on different occasions so I need to see when the user has completed the login.

The user can login via the Welcome controller (via Facebook) or the login controller (via normal methods) and via the Signup (via signup ;).

This is what I have tried to implement below:
**MESHomeViewController.h**

```
#import "MESWelcomeViewController.h"

@interface MESHomeViewController : UIViewController <LoginViewControllerDelegate>

@end
```

In the **MESHomeViewController.m** I check if the user is logged in, if they are not complete the following:

```
NSLog(@"not logged in");
MESWelcomeViewController *loginNavVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"WelcomeVC"];
    loginNavVC.delegate = self;
[self presentModalViewController:loginNavVC animated:NO];
```

In the **MESWelcomeViewController.h** I have the following:

```
@protocol LoginViewControllerDelegate;

@interface MESWelcomeViewController : UIViewController <NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<LoginViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end



@protocol LoginViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)didLoginUser;

@end
```

Once the user is completely logged in via a custom method. **MESWelcomeViewController.m once user logged in**

```
   NSLog(@"%@",self.delegate);
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didLoginUser)]) {
        [self.delegate didLoginUser];
    }
```

However, the delegate method is not being called, it appears the self.delegate is Null for the welcomeViewController. I am thinking possibly I should set the delegate as the Login Nav Controller based on the above setup, but then I am not sure how to call the delegate method from a view controller currently pushed on the nav?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So just to confirm, you have MESHomeViewController, which is your primary view.  From here, you push MESWelcomeViewController onto the stack.  MESWelcomeViewController can perform some login stuff, and once complete, calls [self.delegate didLoginUser].

If this is the case, when you initialize the MESWelcomeViewController, you need to set the delegate.  You can do this easily in several ways.  You could have an init function for MESWelcomeViewController which takes in an id

```
-(id) init:(id<LoginViewControllerDelegate>)myDelegate {
    self = [super init];
    if (self){
        self.delegate = myDelegate;
        etc...
    }
}
```

Alternatively, after creating the MESWelcomeViewController, but before pushing it, set the delegate property

```
MESWelcomeViewController *welcomeView = [[MESWelcomeViewController alloc] init];
[welcomeView setDelegate:self];
// push view stuff
```

---

Edit:

The init function I gave there isn't automatically called, it would have to explicitly be called instead of the default initializer.  If you're using storyboards, you probably should be using the alternative of setting the delegate property.  I've never used storyboards before, but you should probably be able to do something like this:

```
MESWelcomeViewController *welcomeView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"WelcomeVC"];
[welcomeView setDelegate:self];
[self presentModalViewController:welcomeView animated:NO];
```

---

Edit 2:
Best alternative would be to use notifications instead.  Anything that wants to listen adds an observer to the NSNotificationCenter, and when the event occurs, post the notification.

Example:

In MESHomeViewController's initialize or viewDidLoad, put the following:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didLoginUser) name:@"LoginCompleteNotification" object:nil];
```

Then whenever you complete a login, do the following:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"LoginCompleteNotification" object:nil];
```

Finally, make sure that you stop listening in the Dealloc of anything that was listening

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"LoginCompleteNotification object:nil]
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried to use your init, but when I NSLog the self.delegate (within the login complete block) I am still getting (null)? The login is pushed with the following '' [self presentModalViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"WelcomeVC"] animated:NO]; '' This pushes the identifier from storyboard, which points to the LoginNavController (with the Welcome Controller as the root). I am not sure how to implement your second point whilst presenting the modal in this way

Comment: In fact if I add that init function into MESWelcomeViewController it is never called on initialising? Is it correct?

Comment: The init function I gave there isn't automatically called, it would have to explicitly be called instead of the default initializer.  If you're using storyboards, you probably should be using the alternative of setting the delegate property.  I've never used storyboards before, but you should probably be able to do something like this:

    MESWelcomeViewController *welcomeView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"WelcomeVC"];
    [welcomeView setDelegate:self];
    [self presentModalViewController:welcomeView animated:NO];

Comment: what is the alternative? Do I actually need to use a delegate here? All I am trying to do is tell the controller underneath (MESHomeViewController) that the user has logged in, i.e. the modal controller (MESLoginNavController stack possibly with any of the other controllers on) has been dismissed... However, I cannot use viewDidAppear etc because they are regularly shown at later points and I need to run specific code on login which wouldn't be run from the login/welcome/signup controller itself... Could this be accomplished any other way?

Comment: See my edit in the answer.  You can just replace the "[self presentModalViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"WelcomeVC"] animated:NO];"
line with those three lines and it should do the trick.

Comment: That is actually what I was originally doing, see the second part of code in the question for reference I think that is the same. I think the issue is that the storyboard reference to WelcomeVC is actually the navigation controller (LoginNavController) which then has the root controller of MESWelcomeViewController. So I am actually setting the delegate to the wrong controller. However as it is not alloc'd init from the logout and the nav controller is presented instead I do not know how to access the controller within it, how to get a pointer to that?

Comment: Another way, outside of delegates, is to use notifications.
Anything that wants to know about an event listens, and when that event occurs, you post the notification.  I'll put some sample in my answer.

Comment: Notifications is the key here, delegates are way to complicated when used with storyboards and trying to find pointers to random controllers on the stack. THANKS

Answer (score 0):

Either your `ViewController` gets freed by its container or you're setting the `delegate` property too soon.

I'd suggest adding this to the first view controller:

```
- (void) dealloc
{
  NSLog(@"deallocing");
}
```

just to rule out the first option.

To check for the second option, print `loginNavVC` right after setting its `delegate`, make sure it isn't `nil`.

Comment: I have added the following to dealloc to see if it is being deallocated and it is not. NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__); (For Home View Controller). I also added a log 'NSLog(@"%@",loginNavVC.delegate);' which returns the MESHomeViewController as it should. However, the self.delegate Log once logged in is still null?

Comment: I think it is because this line ""MESWelcomeViewController *loginNavVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"WelcomeVC"];"" Actually points to the LoginNavController which is the identifier WelcomeVC, as it has the welcome as the root view controller. So it is like I am setting the loginNavController delegate instead of for the actual welcome view controller but i am unsure how to do that?