# How to reload MasterView Controller TableView from DetailViewController

Tags: ios, ipad, ios7, uisplitviewcontroller

In detail view controller I have formlist. after fill that form I'm storing into array after Save Button click then I'm passing that array into MasterView and Showing Count Of Forms.

Comment: i'm able to pass the value.But cellForRowAtIndexPath Not Calling.

Comment: You can use Protocol or NSNotificationCenter

Comment: Just reload your table after passing the values.

Comment: Check my asnwer about Notification http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17587877/how-to-reload-the-rootviewcontroller-in-another-viewcontroller-in-ipad/17588047#17588047

Comment: it's working fine after using NSNotificationCenter. thank you Nitin Gohel. And thaks to every  one.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look on design patterns. In your above case delegation would be preferred. Notification is another option but it should be used for broadcasting a message.

*objects receiving notifications can react only after the event has occurred. This is a significant difference from delegation. The delegate is given a chance to reject or modify the operation proposed by the delegating object. Observing objects, on the other hand, cannot directly affect an impending operation*

You can read more about on design pattern and viewcontroller interaction:

[How do I set up a simple delegate to communicate between two view controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168919/how-do-i-set-up-a-simple-delegate-to-communicate-between-two-view-controllers)
http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2091958
http://blog.shinetech.com/2011/06/14/delegation-notification-and-observation/