# how to define action in one view controller and call them anywhere

Tags: ios, objective-c

What I have is three button at the top of my app.

Those three buttons will always appear on all view controller.

When I click button, respective action will be taken.

As we have this in all viewcontroller, what I am planning is I will have method defined somewhere which I will call on clicking this button.

I am doing this because I will have method written once and call them anywhere.

ELse I had to write method for all view controller and if there are changes later, I will have to do for all view controllers.

Any idea how can I achieve the same?

***What I want to do is define some method in one UIViewController and call that method in many different ViewController.***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider creating your own container view controller and add your true content view controllers as children (using `addChildViewController:`). Then your container view controller can manage the global buttons and their actions without affecting any of the actual content view controllers.

Comment: nice point... just to clarify, let's say I made GlobalViewController and have the button action in this viewcontroller... now I will create another class which is subclass of GlobalViewController (`@interface WelcomeViewController : GlobalViewController`). Right?

Comment: but in this case, I believe I need to create button programmatically as I connect using storyboard to my GlobalViewController. Right?

Comment: No, you wouldn't usually subclass the 'GlobalViewController'. There isn't really any good reason to. You can have the view controllers defined in your storyboard and load them by identifier.

Comment: can you check what I have done and let me know if this is fine?

Answer (score 1):

Another technique aside from having a container view controller is to have each of your viewControllers subclass another viewcontroller in your project.

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController; // implements your buttons and their actions

@interface OneViewController : MainViewController;
@interface TwoViewController : MainViewController;
@interface ThreeViewController : MainViewController;
```

Comment: can you see my comments in Wain answer? do you agree?

Comment: @Wain's answer is slightly different. Take a look at the `UIViewController` documentation and decide if you want to use the child view controller arrangement.

Comment: in your case, I will have to create button programmatically... right? else I can't call action defined in MainViewController for OneViewController... right?

Comment: OneViewController subclasses MainViewController, and inherits all of MainViewController's instance variables and methods.

Answer (score 1):

Although subclassing is an option, using Objective-C categories will give you greater flexibility.

Create a category that extends UIViewController:

```
@interface UIViewController (SharedLogic)

- (void)didPressFirstButton:(id)sender;
- (void)didPressSecondButton:(id)sender;
- (void)didPressThirdButton:(id)sender;

@end
```

Whatever classes specifies the target/action pair for each button will need to `#import` this category, but otherwise you should get the behavior you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with delegates...here's a nice explanation of this:

[How do I set up a simple delegate to communicate between two view controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168919/how-do-i-set-up-a-simple-delegate-to-communicate-between-two-view-controllers)

Answer (score 0):

What I did is as below and it's working.

Created UIViewController as `TopBarViewController` which is common for all.

### TopBarViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface TopBarViewController : UIViewController
- (IBAction)clickedSetting:(id)sender;
@end
```

### TopBarViewController.m

```
#import "TopBarViewController.h"
@interface TopBarViewController ()
@end
@implementation TopBarViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)clickedSetting:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"clickedSetting-TopBar");
    // do your action here
}

@end
```

Now when I click button in MyViewController, I call action as below.

```
- (IBAction)clickedSetting:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"self-clickedSetting");
    topBarViewCon = [[TopBarViewController alloc] init];
    [topBarViewCon clickedSetting:nil];
}
```

I have `@property (nonatomic, retain) TopBarViewController *topBarViewCon;` in .h file & synthesize this property in .m file.

Is this right way is this is wrong way?

Comment: If you are trying to follow my answer then this is the wrong way. You should have 1 instance of `TopBarViewController` which is created by the app delegate and is the container for your other view controllers. What you have is all of the other view controllers creating instances of `TopBarViewController` to handle the button selection - very wasteful and not a good structure.

Comment: @Wain : I can create in Appdelegate, but TopBarViewController is only used after user login in my system (means after first 5-6 view controller). So can I ignore in view controller when I don't want to use them? The problem is I don't have same structure for full app...

Comment: Ok, so after login you would create the `TopBarViewController` instance, add at least 1 child view controller and and push it to the screen. Please read https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html

Answer (score 0):

Consider using NSNotificationCenter to broadcast UI events to different places in your codebase.