# How to call a method in a container class from a "contained" class

Tags: objective-c

I have these two classes, Class A and Class B. Class A has an instance of Class B as an instance variable. Is there way for Class B to send a message to Class A or invoke one of its methods?

Comment: The instance of class B contained in A does not know about the A it's contained in. Thus without some modification to alert class B of the instance of class A this is not possible. You might wanna consider creating a delegate protocol for class A to implement and then setting A as B's delegate, but this is kind of circular and not the best design

Comment: is classA super class of classB ?

Comment: @Pryatham51 no Class A is not a supoer class of Class B, B is merely contained in Class A

Comment: @HugoT I've been advised that I could pass a pointer to Class A instance onto Class B's constructor. Could this work?

Comment: @TheDarkBugReturns Yes this could work and will work well if the B instance is created inside A and does not come from the outside, but you will still have a circular dependency between A and B. This is not ideal.

Comment: @HugoT Okay, is there a way I can notify or pass message to class A ?

Comment: @TheDarkBugReturns As Adis wrote in his answer and I suggested earlier use the delegate pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with the protocol-delegate paradigm. Check here for the official documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html

Take a look at the similar question here:
[How do I set up a simple delegate to communicate between two view controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168919/how-do-i-set-up-a-simple-delegate-to-communicate-between-two-view-controllers)