# Split View Controllers: Initiate a segue from a detail view that effects the Master View

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uisplitviewcontroller, segue

Ok So I am very new to XCode and IOS but essentially what I have is this:

I have a split view controller that is used in my app to display a small amount of basic information on an attraction or loaction on the left (in the master view controller) and presents the user with the options/reviews/ or other choices in the detail view controller.

Now what I am trying to do:
- when the user selects an attraction from the dynamically generated table of attractions in the detail view I want it to not only trigger a segue that reveals more information on that in the detail view but also trigger a segue in the master view to change to a short blurb of the attraction.

does anyone know how I'd go about this? I am using Xcode 5

Thank you for your Help

screenshot can be found here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is plenty of ways you could go about this, but probably the best way is to implement a custom protocol-delegate paradigm that will trigger a piece of code in your master view, which will then invoke a segue in that view.

There is a similar question in this question regarding the navigation stack, but it will work with concurrent controllers as well:

[How do I set up a simple delegate to communicate between two view controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168919/how-do-i-set-up-a-simple-delegate-to-communicate-between-two-view-controllers)

Here are Apple's basics regarding the protocols:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html

In a nutshell, you would define a protocol in your master view, with one method that invokes the segue depending on the selected cell in the detail view, you would probably pass the model of the location through the method as well.

```
@protocol LocationDelegate

- (void)didSelectLocation:(MyLocation *)location;

@end
```

Your table of attractions would have a delegate property pointing to the master view which you would set up at the creation time.

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <LocationDelegate> *delegate;
```

When you select a cell in the table of attractions, you would call the delegate method to do it's magic.

```
[self.delegate didSelectLocation:location];
```