# passing data to a childViewController from the view controller that holds the container view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

In my application I created a container view(called `ContainerViewController`) on the top of an another view(called `GameViewController`,where I keep the game logic and api callbacks).I also have other views and an api class.My container view contains 3 `views` and I am trying to pass some objects to one of my container view(VC1). Since `GameViewController` is only connected to `ContainerViewController`(meaning there is no `segue` directly, so I can't use prepareforsegue and I can't use `presentViewController`, since they `childViewControllers`), I can't pass data. 
I also tried just getting the values from my deserializer class(inside vc1). The problem with that was the VC1 gets called before.

my question is, how can I set values of VC1 from my callback inside the `GameViewController`?
This is what my storyboard looks like:[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Use `NSNotificationCenter` .

Comment: Use a protocol and delegate and have a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168919/how-do-i-set-up-a-simple-delegate-to-communicate-between-two-view-controllers

If you are not familiar with notification, you will send a lot of notifications without removing the old one.

Comment: @JordanMontel, aren't we suppose to use protocol and delegate, when passing data backwards only?

Comment: It's easier. Use `property` to pass data from A to B and use `protocol` to pass data backward from B to A

Answer (score 1):

You can do it many ways:

1st way : You can pass the data using Notification.

2nd way : You can create a separate singleton data model class to store your game data. Then you can access the object of that class among your view controllers to set the properties in view controllers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try and let you know.