# Custom UIView inside a UIViewController button click to refresh UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a custom UIView which has been loaded into a different `UIViewController`. I have a button in the custom `UIView`, which calls a method inside its own class. I want this method to refresh the `UIViewController` which the `UIView` is embeded in. Currently I have tried importing the `UIViewController` to the UIView initializing it and then calling a public method which i have put inside the UIViewController. Nothing that happens inside this method seems to affect it though, I have even tried changing the `navigation bar` title and that wont work. I know the method is getting called though as it comes up in my log.

Any help?

Comment: Please make your question clearer, hopefully with code. Its kind of hard to understand what you want from the block of text. Thanks!

Comment: it would be very hard to post code for this without it being a very large amount. I basically want to refresh a view from another view.

Comment: Aha, I think in this case what you need is a delegate protocol, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168919/how-do-i-set-up-a-simple-delegate-to-communicate-between-two-view-controllers

Answer (score 1):

This is where a delegation pattern comes into action. If I have not misunderstood, you want to perform some action(refresh??) on a `UIViewController` based on some action in a `UIView`, which is in turn is a part of its own view hierarchy.

Lets say your custom view is wrapped in a class `CustomView`. It has a method named `action` that is invoked at some point. Moreover, lets assume that you have used `CustomView` instances to some view controllers, namely, `MyViewController1`, `MyViewController2`, etc, as a part of their view hierarchies. Now, you want to perform some action (refresh) in your VCS when `action` method is triggered from your `CustomView` instances. For this purpose, you need to declare a protocol in the header file of your `CustomView` and will have to register a handler of this protocol (commonly known as delegate) to an instance of the `CustomView`. The header file would look something like this:

```
//CustomView.h
//your include headers...

@class CustomView;

@protocol CustomViewDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)customViewDidPerformAction:(CustomView*)customView;
@end

@interface CustomView : UIView {
    //......... your ivars
    id<CustomViewDelegate> _delegate;
}

//.......your properties
@property(nonatomic,weak) id<CustomViewDelegate> delegate;

-(void)action;
//....other declarations
@end
```

Now, you would like `customViewDidPerformAction` method to be called from any class (like a view controller for "refresh" purpose) whenever `action` method is triggered. For that purpose, in your implementation file (CustomView.m), you need to invoke the `customViewDidPerformAction` method stub, if available, from inside your `action` method:

```
//CustomView.m
//.......initializer and other codes
-(void)action {
    //other codes

    //raise a callback notifying action has been performed
    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(customViewDidPerformAction:)]) {
        [self.delegate customViewDidPerformAction:self];
    }
}
```

Now, any class that conforms to `CustomViewDelegate` protocol can register itself as a receiver of the callback `customViewDidPerformAction:`. For example, lets say, our `MyViewController1` view controller class conforms to the protocol. So the header to the class would look something like this:

```
//MyViewController1.h
//include headers

@interface MyViewController1 : UIViewController<CustomViewDelegate> 

//........your properties, methods, etc
@property(nonatomic,strong) CustomView* myCustomView;
//......
@end
```

Then you need to register this class as a `delegate` of `myCustomView`, after instantiating `myCustomView`. Say you have instantiated `myCustomView` in the `viewDidLoad` method of the VC. So the method body would be something similar to:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    ////...........other codes

    CustomView* cv = [[CustomView alloc] initWithFrame:<# your frame size #>];
    cv.delegate = self;
    self.myCustomView = cv;
    [cv release];

    ////......other codes
}
```

Then you also need to create a method with the same method signature as the protocol declares, inside the implementation(.m) file of the same VC and right your "refresh" code there:

```
-(void)customViewDidPerformAction:(CustomView*)customView {
    ///write your refresh code here
}
```

And you are all set. `MyViewController1` would execute your refresh code whenever `action` method is performed by `CustomView`.

You can follow the same mechanism (conform to `CustomViewDelegate` protocol and implement `customViewDidPerformAction:` method) from within any VC, containing a `CustomView` in its view hierarchy, to refresh itself whenever the `action` is triggered.