# Delegate in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, delegates

I am new at Objective-C, and I'm trying to understand delegates. I have searched and read a lot, but nothing is really helping me understand. I think that best way to understand this might be asking a question with a sample app.

I'm trying to create a grade calculator application to test my skills. Here are my files:

> mainTableViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface mainTableViewController : UITableViewController

@end
```

mainTableViewController.m

```
#import "mainTableViewController.h"
#import "addLectureViewController.h"


@interface mainTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation anaTableViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    [lectureName count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}

@end
```

addLectureViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface addLectureViewController : UIViewController 
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *lectureNameTextField;
- (IBAction)addButtonPressed:(id)sender;

@property NSMutableArray *lectureName; 
@property NSObject *lecture;

@end
```

addLectureViewController.m

```
#import "addLectureViewController.h"

@interface addLectureViewController ()

@end

@implementation addLectureViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _lectureName = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    _lecture = [[NSObject alloc] init];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}

- (IBAction)addButtonPressed:(id)sender {

    _lecture = _lectureNameTextField.text;
    [_lectureName addObject:_lecture];
    NSLog(@"%@",_lectureName);


}
@end
```

Everything is okay so far. But when i try to use the `_lectureName` `NSMutableArray` at mainTableViewController.m, I can't see the array.

I know the codes for printing the array in tableView. I know they are not at there right now. I just don't understand implement delegate codes to my code.

Comment: Why did you include the `anaTableViewController` code when it doesn't appear to be used anywhere?

Comment: but where is delegates?

Comment: You mean you want to transfer the data of **_lectureName** to **mainTableViewController**??

Comment: i mistype the anaTableViewController thing. I fixed it right now. I wanted to type mainTableViewController.

And yes i mean the transferring data of _lectureName to mainTableViewController yes.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you add screenshots of your app?? or can you specify if u have used any **segue** between the **mainTableViewController** and **addLectureViewController**?

Comment: i didn't use any segue between those two. the parent is mainTableViewController and the child is addLectureViewController. And i just want to call back an array from child to parent. And i thought that this is about delegate right ?

Comment: Without having a **Segue** how can u establish a relationship between those two views??? And when u add some data using addLectureViewController and you wish this data to be available mainTableViewController you need to have a relationship b/w them.

Comment: @iamyogish - There are a dozen different ways to establish a "relationship" between view controllers, but of course one must employ one of them if communication between the two is expected.

Comment: Basically, when you create the second VC you should, after creating it, set it's `delegate` property to point to a delegate object that has access to the first VC's data.  Quite often this would be a pointer to the first VC itself.  Then, in the second VC, one invokes methods of the delegate object (usually defined in a "protocol" to keep them distinct) to access the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If You want to display something on the rows of the table, You can take an NSArray and you have to return the count of the array in the delegate method:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
 return array.count;
}
```

Otherwise, table will not display any elements. And delegate method cellForRowAtIndexPath will only be called if you are returning a particular array count of number count in your numberOfRowsInSection method.

You can take reference from these links to understand delegates:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_delegates.htm

[How do I set up a simple delegate to communicate between two view controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168919/how-do-i-set-up-a-simple-delegate-to-communicate-between-two-view-controllers)

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-custom-delegates--mobile-10848

But in the case of tableView, the delegate methods are internally defined and triggered internally. We just need to set those delegates to the controller which acts as a listener.

Comment: Thanks but i know that i just forgot to write it down there. Which is i edited now. I just want to understand that the delegate codes. Which codes should i write to delegate my array to other page ? I would be very happy if you can help me. Thanks.

Comment: I edited my answer. Look at it. The UITableView delegate methods are predefined and are called as soon as you set tableview.delegate = self. This is basically a callback mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

The below code might have syntax errors but they can provide a summary of delegates for this code.

Make the following changes :-

mainTableViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface mainTableViewController : UITableViewController
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *lectureName
@end
```

Synthesize the property lectureName in mainTableViewController.m

Then make the following changes in addLectureViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "mainTableViewController.h"

@interface addLectureViewController : UIViewController 
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *lectureNameTextField;
- (IBAction)addButtonPressed:(id)sender;
@property(weak, nonatomic) id<mainTableViewController> delegate;
@property NSMutableArray *lectureName; 
@property NSObject *lecture;

@end
```

Synthesize the property delegate in addLectureViewController.m

Then make the following change :-

```
- (IBAction)addButtonPressed:(id)sender {

    _lecture = _lectureNameTextField.text;
    [_lectureName addObject:_lecture];
    NSLog(@"%@",_lectureName);
    delegate.lectureName=_lectureName;
}
```

Assuming that you are pushing addLectureViewController from mainTableViewController, also include the following code in prepareForSegue of mainTableViewController (or whatever method in which you are pushing addLectureViewController). :-

```
addLectureViewController *vc=[[addLectureViewController alloc] init];
vc.delegate=self;
// Push vc
```

The above code actually creates a weak property of type `id<mainTableViewController>` called delegate (weak in order to prevent reference cycles). This way, addLectureViewController can update mainTableViewController's property.

Answer (score 0):

Points:

1. Why is the class in `mainTableViewController.m` named `anaTableViewController`. It should be `mainTableViewController` (almost always, until you get more advanced).
2. `mainTableViewController` and `addLectureViewController` should start with capital letters.
3. The only way for `mainTableViewController` to access `lecture` is through a `addLectureViewController` object, e.g.

   ```
   addLectureViewController *alvc = // *something* here
   NSArray *localLecture = [alvc lecture];
   ```

   Figure out how you have access to an `addLectureViewController` and you will have solved your problem.