# chartboost didDisplayInterstitial

Tags: xcode, chartboost

this is probably a dumb question, but I would like to be notified when a ChartBoost-ad is displaying for the user. I see in the chartboost.h, there is a a few delegates, one in particular of interest, the didDisplayInterstatial.

I do not however know how to implement this, or if it is used for this at all.

chartboost.h

```
@protocol ChartboostDelegate <NSObject>
@optional

/// All of the delegate methods below are optional.
/// Implement them only when you need to more finely control Chartboost's behavior.

/// Called before requesting an interestitial from the back-end
- (BOOL)shouldRequestInterstitial:(CBLocation)location;

// Called when an interstitial has been displayed on the screen.
- (void)didDisplayInterstitial:(CBLocation)location;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking how to use those delegate/protocol methods?

If so, it's covered really well in Apple's iOS tutorials https://developer.apple.com/videos/ and in forums, e.g. [How do I set up a simple delegate to communicate between two view controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168919/how-do-i-set-up-a-simple-delegate-to-communicate-between-two-view-controllers)