# iOS show view controller from NSObject not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to show a image picker view controller from a NSObject subclass but when i call  presentViewController on the app's root vc the app crashes without a error message.

My code is here:

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;

UIViewController *root = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:0] rootViewController];

[root presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

If i run this in a view controller it just works fine.

**EDIT:**

I can't use a delegate because i am building a plugin for Unity and i can't get the view controller in other ways than this.

I noticed the crash while calling this code in the current view controller from a IBAction:

```
- (IBAction)showPicker:(id)sender {
    PhotoManager *manager = [[PhotoManager alloc] init];
    [manager loadPhoto];
}
```

In answer to the comments here's the class code:

PhotoManager.h:

```
@interface PhotoManager : NSObject <UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>

- (void)loadPhoto;

@end
```

.m:

```
@implementation PhotoManager {
    UIViewController *root;
}

- (void)loadPhoto {
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;

    root = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:0] rootViewController];

    [root presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [root dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@", info);
}

@end
```

Comment: This code is not relevant, its the SubClass we need to see, and how you call this code. Good luck

Comment: provide also stacktrace showing what error you get when it crashes

Comment: Walter said it crashes without error messages

Answer (score 0):

The proper way would be to create a protocol / delegate and call back to the presenting viewController telling it to present the picker. This allows you to do much more and is a great habit to learn right away IMO.

[How do I set up a simple delegate to communicate between two view controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168919/how-do-i-set-up-a-simple-delegate-to-communicate-between-two-view-controllers)