# multiple view controllers involved, how to send a value back to starting view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I am very new to `iOS` and overwhelmed with resources I find online.  My use case is simple

a.) ViewController `parent` has label called `categoryLabel`. A tap on label `category` opens a new view `View 1`
b.) `View 1`, shows all groups. Lets says `A, B, C`. This will be shown on table
c.) when user click on any group `A, B or C`, a new view `View 2` appears with all categories in that group. For example, user clicks on `A` and on `View 2` user sees categories `A1, A2, A3`.
d.) Now when user clicks on any specific category, how does that goes back to ViewController `parent` and assigns to `categoryLabel`?

I do not know what is the best way to approach this design.
Any guidance is very much appreciated

Comment: You can use the delegate method pattern from iOS. check the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168919/how-do-i-set-up-a-simple-delegate-to-communicate-between-two-view-controllers

Comment: If you're using a storyboard with segues, then you can use an unwind segue to go back to the first controller, and pass data to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope this will help

let take an example , your are going from A -> B and want send some data from B to A  , there are many technique to do that but using delegate method and block are nicer way.

delegate way :-

in your `B.h` file

```
@protocol yourDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)whichCategoryClicked:(NSString *)categoryName;

@end

@interface B : UIView
@property(nonatomic, assign)id<yourDelegate> delegate;
```

in your `B.m`

just call this delegate method after Clicking particular category.

```
[self.delegate whichCategoryClicked :@"Category_name"];
```

in your `A.h`

assign it as delegate and import the above class

```
@interface A.h : UIViewController<yourDelegate>
```

and in Implement this method in `A.m`

first in your viewdidload

{

---

```
 B *objB = [[B alloc]init];
    objB.delegate = self;
```

---

}

```
-(void)whichCategoryClicked:(NSString *)categoryName
{
categoryLabel.text = categoryName;
}
```

Comment: What is `DXSemiButtonDelegate`?

Comment: srry @daydreamer typo mistake

Answer (score 0):

You can use Local notification for this purpose names as NSNotificationCenter in iOS. Which works as follows:

To send a notification that is from the view on which you are and want to send some value from that view, use below code:

```
NSDictionary *dict;
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"NotificationKey" object:nil userInfo:dict];
```

and now on any of the view controller, you can add observer on viewDidLoad of that class as:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                selector:@selector(methodToCall:)
                                                 name:@"NotificationKey"
                                               object:nil];
```

Now call method written in above line:

```
- (void)updateImageFromArray:(NSNotification *)notification {
    // your dict
    NSDictionary *dictUserInfo = [notification userInfo];

}
```