# Stopping Audio from different class

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, avaudioplayer

Note: I have looked at other questions and the answers to them are quite vague or unhelpful

I have this code in `View_Controller.h`

```
@property AVAudioPlayer *playerSaxophone;
```

Then I do this in the same file (in `viewDidLoad`):

```
NSURL *backgroundMusicSaxophone = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:
                          [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                           pathForResource:@"saxophone" ofType:@"wav"]];
self.playerSaxophone = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
          initWithContentsOfURL:backgroundMusicSaxophone error:nil];

self.playerSaxophone.numberOfLoops = -1;

[self.playerSaxophone setVolume:0.5];
[self.playerSaxophone play];
```

In a different view controller I want to be able to stop or start this audio from playing by clicking 2 buttons. Is there any way I can do this?

Edit: I tried this in the "different" view controller .m file

```
//I do import ViewController.h in this file
- (IBAction)stop:(id)sender {
    ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    [viewController.playerSaxophone stop];
}
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call:

```
[playerSaxophone stop];
```

to make the music stop.

Problem: Another view controller won't have a reference to `playerSaxophone`.

The fact that you want to add code that references this from another view controller means you'll have to find a way to have the three objects - view controller A, view controller B, and your audio player - communicate.

Here are a few options:

1. Use the delegation pattern to have one view controller tell the other view controller to stop the player.
2. The same as #1, but using the notification pattern. (This is ideal if you'd have a 3rd place that controls the player).
3. You could move `playerSaxophone` to be a `@property` on either your App Delegate or a singleton. Then each view controller will be able to find it.

These are just a few solutions. There are others.

Additional reading:

- Apple's [Coordinating Efforts Between View Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ManagingDataFlowBetweenViewControllers/ManagingDataFlowBetweenViewControllers.html)
- [This Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9736559/1445366)
- [How do I set up a simple delegate to communicate between two view controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6168919/1445366)

Comment: Your edit doesn't work because you're creating a *new* instance of `ViewController` instead of pointing to the one that you've already created.