# Swift sending data from child view to parent view controller

Tags: ios, swift

I am developing an app where I have a view controller and subview. On the subview I am loading Google maps and on the main view I have a label.

My question is how can I pass data from the subview (map geo location) to the label on the main view and have this updated as the location is updated using Swift.

All the tutorials I have found use prepareForSegue where I would like to just update the label automatically as it is on the main view.

Thanks

Updated: I can't seem to get the delegate method to work. Code below.

MapChildController.swift

```
import UIKit

protocol ChildViewControllerDelegate{
    func delegateMethod(childViewController:MapChildController, text:String)
}

class MapChildController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var didFindMyLocation = false
var myLocations: [CLLocation] = []

var delegate:ChildViewControllerDelegate?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    var camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(-33.86, longitude: 151.20, zoom: 15, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 45)
    var mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera: camera)

    mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
    self.view = mapView

    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

    if NSProcessInfo().isOperatingSystemAtLeastVersion(NSOperatingSystemVersion(majorVersion: 8, minorVersion: 0, patchVersion: 0)) {
        println("iOS >= 8.0.0")
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        //locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    }

    mapView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "myLocation", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: nil)

    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    //locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String, ofObject object: AnyObject, change: [NSObject : AnyObject], context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    if !didFindMyLocation {
        let myLocation: CLLocation = change[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] as! CLLocation
        var mapView = self.view as! GMSMapView
        mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithTarget(myLocation.coordinate, zoom: 15.0)
        mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
        didFindMyLocation = true
    }
}

func locationManager(manager:CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations:[AnyObject]) {

    // println("Last location: \(locations.last)")
    self.delegate?.delegateMethod(self, text: "from child")
}
}
```

MapController.swift

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class MapController : UIViewController, ChildViewControllerDelegate
{
@IBOutlet weak var Label: UILabel!
var LabelText = String()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func delegateMethod(controller: MapChildController, text: String) {
    println("The text is " +  text);
}
}
```

Comment: Your title and your text don't match. Do you have a subview with Google Maps, or is that another view controller? If the latter, have you added it as a child view controller of your main view controller?

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the title. I am wanting to send geo locations from child view (which has Google map) to the parent view (which has the label).

Comment: Use delegation. Make the main view controller, the delegate of the view, and have the view call method (defined in a delegate protocol) on its delegate when it needs to.

Comment: OK great. I am new to Swift development so I will look around for that and see what I can come up with.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Delegation pattern is your friend.

Declare a protocol on your child view controller that the parent view controller will implement. Whenever you want, call a method on the delegate reference you are holding in the child view controller - this will update the parent view controller with data from child VC.

This SO question explains the child parent delegation neatly [How do I set up a simple delegate to communicate between two view controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168919/how-do-i-set-up-a-simple-delegate-to-communicate-between-two-view-controllers)

Answer (score 4):

I see some answers here, so you can solve your problem changing some lines in your code, look at:

```
protocol ChildViewControllerDelegate{
    func delegateMethod(childViewController:MapChildController, text:String)
}
```

I used without the `childViewController` passing by method then you could just pass whatever you want send to another view just saying what type of data you want send, in case it's a String. So you can change the `ChildViewControllerDelegate` to:

```
protocol ChildViewControllerDelegate{
    func delegateMethod(text:String)
}
```

You need do the same thing in class `MapController`:

```
func delegateMethod(text: String) {
    println("The text is " +  text);
}
```

You can see a better explanation in: [How to send data back by popViewControllerAnimated for Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30618172/how-to-send-data-back-by-popviewcontrolleranimated-for-swift)

Answer (score 1):

```
 self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        let vc = self.navigationController?.viewControllers.last as! MainViewController
        vc.textfield.text = "test"
```

you can do like if you want maybe you dont need this answer but other users for useful

Answer (score 0):

```
var delegate:ChildViewControllerDelegate?
```

In addition to this, you also need to do this to make the delegate work:

```
delegate = MapController()
```