# How to send data back by popViewControllerAnimated for Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I need to send some data back from secondView to First View by popView.
How can i send back the data by popViewControllerAnimated?

Thanks!

Comment: if you have small data then you can use NSUserDefaluts  or NSNotificaitonCenter.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13509832/it-possible-to-pass-data-with-popviewcontrolleranimated

Comment: here is a TRUE way to use the delegate with popViewControllerAnimated in Swift!: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39692791/swift-how-to-call-delegate-with-popviewcontroller

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You can pass data back using `delegate`

1. Create `protocol` in `ChildViewController`
2. Create `delegate` variable in `ChildViewController`
3. Extend `ChildViewController` protocol in `MainViewController`
4. Give reference to `ChildViewController` of `MainViewController` when `navigate`
5. Define `delegate` Method in `MainViewController`
6. Then you can call `delegate` method from `ChildViewController`

**Example**

**In ChildViewController**: Write code below...

```
protocol ChildViewControllerDelegate
{
     func childViewControllerResponse(parameter)
}

class ChildViewController:UIViewController
{
    var delegate: ChildViewControllerDelegate?
    ....
}
```

**In MainViewController**

```
// extend `delegate`
class MainViewController:UIViewController,ChildViewControllerDelegate
{
    // Define Delegate Method
    func childViewControllerResponse(parameter)
    {
       .... // self.parameter = parameter
    }
}
```

There are two options:

A) with Segue

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
{
   let goNext = segue.destinationViewController as ChildViewController
   goNext.delegate = self
}
```

B) without Segue

```
let goNext = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("childView") as ChildViewController
goNext.delegate = self
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(goNext, animated: true)
```

**Method Call**

```
self.delegate?.childViewControllerResponse(parameter)
```

Comment: here is a TRUE way to use the delegate with popViewControllerAnimated in Swift!: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39692791/swift-how-to-call-delegate-with-popviewcontroller

Comment: Marvellous content

Comment: but iam not pushing but poping a view controller so what should i do that?

Comment: @DavidSeek how different is solution from your question? It seems to be duplicate

Comment: i dont know what went on 2 freaking years ago xD seems the same. maybe something didnt work. i dont know. seems legit answer tho

Comment: Cannot find type 'parameter' in scope

Answer (score 22):

If you want to send data by popping, you'd do something like:

```
func goToFirstViewController() {
  let a = self.navigationController.viewControllers[0] as A
  a.data = "data"
  self.navigationController.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

Comment: If i want to popback to previousView but not first view, how can i fix it?

Comment: you should use delegate for this purpose

Comment: @VarisDarasirikul `self.navigationController.popToViewController(a, animated: true)`

Comment: @VarisDarasirikul set the index to the view controller you want.  In my case it was 1 not 0.  let a = self.navigationController?.viewControllers[1] as! YourPreviousViewController.     Awesome answer BTW :)

Comment: Definitely an awesome answer. Learn something new every day, it’s very clever, thanks!

Comment: This approach prohibits the re-usability of that view controller, I think delegates are preferable.

Answer (score 2):

Extending Dheeraj's answer in case your `ViewController` is not first VC in the stack, here is the solution:

```
func popViewController() {
  guard let myVC = self.navigationController?.viewControllers.first({ $0 is MyViewController }) else { return } 
  myVC.data = "data"
  self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

However, this solution will break if you have 2 or more than 2 `MyViewController` in the stack. So, use wisely.

Answer (score 0):

Answer given here is a little complex, quite simple to just use [UINavigationControllerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontrollerdelegate)

```
class FirstNavigationController: UIViewController {
    var value: String?
}

class SecondNavigationController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        guard let vc = navigationController.topViewController as? FirstNavigationController else { return }
        vc.value = "Hello again"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        let vc = self.navigationController?.viewControllers.last as! MainViewController
        vc.textfield.text = "test"
```

this popviewcontroller solutions