# Update/Reload ViewController when cell selected in UITableView (swift2)

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uibutton, nsuserdefaults

My question is how to update or reload ViewController when cell selected in UITableView.
I have ViewController with two buttons and when you click on one of them you will go to tableViewController and when you select one option, the option will be saved by

> NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

and tableViewController will dismiss by

> self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

.
I used

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)

    let lang_name = cell!.textLabel!.text!
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(lang_name,forKey:"lang_saved")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)     
}
```

and

```
super.viewDidLoad()
if let lang_saved = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("lang_saved") {
     button1.setTitle("\(lang_saved)", forState: .Normal)
}
```

My problem is I must restart my app to get right result, I mean that the viewcontroller must be reloaded to get button name from

> NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

how can I solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this link: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30618172/how-to-send-data-back-by-popviewcontrolleranimated-for-swift)

You should put your reload code in:

```
// Define Delegate Method
func childViewControllerResponse(parameter)
{
   .... // self.parameter = parameter
}
```

OR

Maybe call

```
if let lang_saved = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("lang_saved") {

        button1.setTitle("\(lang_saved)", forState: .Normal)
    }
```

in `viewWillAppear`

Answer (score 0):

To Reload you button, you must call this code again, when you want to update the button ( it may be on the click, or in the `viewWillAppear` function )

```
        if let lang_saved = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("lang_saved") {
             button1.setTitle("\(lang_saved)", forState: .Normal)
        }
```

The problem with your code is you call only on `viewDidLoad` and this execute only ones when your view is loaded.

Comment: thank you, but I don't want to reload a table view ,  I want to reload view controller which I came from which have buttons I want to update

Comment: wow, in that case just call the query from NSUserDefault again. I will rewrite the answer.