# Set Button Title not showing on UI in Swift

Tags: swift, ios13

**What I want to achieve?**
I have 2 `UITableViewController : AddCardVC` and `ListDeckController`. I want to pass selected Deck in `ListDeckController` to `AddCardVC` then `updateUI` on `AddCardVC`

**My code:** (I'm building on `Swift 5`, `iOS 13`)

> ListDeckController.swift:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    if let addCardVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AddCard") as? AddCardVC {
        if let deck = allDecks?[indexPath.row] {
            addCardVC.selectedDeck = deck
        }
    }
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

> AddCardVC.swift:

```
var selectedDeck: Deck?
    {
        didSet {
            viewWillAppear(true)
        }
    }

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        if let deck = selectedDeck {
            //Update UI
            self.chooseDeckButton.setTitle(deck.name, for: .normal)
            print(chooseDeckButton.titleLabel?.text ?? "")

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

**What happend?**

After I got selected Deck in `AddCardVC`, the console print out `chooseDeckButton.titleLabel?.text = "My Deck"` which is what I want. But The button title on UI is "Choose your deck"
[Console image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhLl2.png)     [Button on UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7v69e.png)

**So, why the setButtonTitle not showing on UI in my case?**

Thank you for your time

Comment: That is not how you send data back to view controller. Use delegates

Comment: your chooseDeckButton is in TableCell ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30618172/how-to-send-data-back-by-popviewcontrolleranimated-for-swift

Comment: @iOSArchitect.com, Yes that's right way to pass data using delegate, but here passing data is not the issue but the button title assignment

Comment: @AnandPrakash He is creating a new instance of addCardVC. instead of refering to previous one. That will never work. He needs to get the previous controller instead. Thats why i said, use delegates

Comment: Yes exactly , please use the shared url to follow the delegate pattern: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30618172/how-to-send-data-back-by-popviewcontrolleranimated-for-swift

Comment: @Vinh check my answer

Comment: @iiOSArchitect.com, I followed your guide but it crash my App. The reason is chooseDeckButton is nil on UI when **didSelectDeck(selectedDeck : Deck)** is called. So I tried to called self.selectedDeck = selectedDeck in **didSelectDeck(selectedDeck : Deck)** then update UI on ViewWillAppear like my previous code but the button title on UI still not change

Comment: @Anand Prakash, yes, my chooseDeckButton is in a cell of a Static Table View

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, create a protocol for DeckDelegate

```
protocol SelectedDeckDelegate {
    func didSelectDeck(selectedDeck : Deck)
}
```

Now in your ListDeckController.swift, implement the delegate

```
var deckDelegate : SelectedDeckDelegate?

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) 
{ 
if let deck = allDecks?[indexPath.row] {
    deckDelegate?.didSelectDeck(selectedDeck: deck)
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
} else {
    print("deck is empty")
}  
}
```

And in your AddCardVC, when navigating to ListDeckController, assign the delegate to self

```
// Make AddCardVC conform to SelectedDeckDelegate

class AddCardVC : UIViewController, SelectedDeckDelegate {


   override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        if let deck = selectedDeck {
            //Update UI
            self.chooseDeckButton.setTitle(deck.name, for: .normal)
            print(chooseDeckButton.titleLabel?.text ?? "")

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    // assign the delegate to self here

    @IBAction func selectDeckBtnAction(_ sender : Any) {
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ListDeckController") as? ListDeckController
        vc.deckDelegate = self
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }

    // this will get called whenever selectedDeck is updated from ListDeckController
    func didSelectDeck(selectedDeck: Deck) {
        self.selectedDeck = selectedDeck
        chooseDeckButton.setTitle(selectedDeck.name , for: .normal)
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I followed your guide but my app crashed. When **func didSelectDeck(selectedDeck: Deck)** is called, the **chooseDeckButton** is nil. So I tried to called **self.selectedDeck = selectedDeck** in **didSelectDeck(selectedDeck : Deck)** then update UI on **ViewWillAppear** like my previous code but the button title on UI still not change

Comment: chooseDeckBtn is nil ? Are you sure? can you share your complete ListDeckController and AddCArdVC code here

Comment: @ iOSArchitect.com, sorry, after i clean up my code, it worked. Your answer is correct. Thank you a lot