# Pushing detail controller from cell of programatically created UITableView inside another view controller

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

I have a custom UIViewController that we'll just call ViewController. I'm using [this](https://github.com/AdityaDeshmane/iOSCustomPageControl) library to have a  view controller effect where one can slide left and right between pages. My pages are a programmatically created UITableView subclass. To be more specific, each page is a Day and the title of the page is the day of the week, and the cells in the UITableView subclass are events for that day.

I want to push to a new view controller when I touch one of these cells but I'm stuck. I want to push to a view controller that I've created in my storyboard and pass an object through that push that populates the view controller. My navigation controller I use in ViewController is created in storyboard. The custom UITableView is created programmatically.

Some errors I've been getting:

-- Application tried to push a nil view controller on target .

-- And also self.navigationController is nil.

I have no idea how to do this and there doesn't seem to be any helpful answer out there. I'm completely stuck. I've attached an image of my ViewController, and if you check out the linked GitHub repo you can see how I'm using the provided code there.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out using a delegate. I pass a delegate in my subclass UITableView back to my original ViewController. In my case it was an object. Check out this link:

[How do I set up a simple delegate to communicate between two view controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168919/how-do-i-set-up-a-simple-delegate-to-communicate-between-two-view-controllers)