# Perform a segue from an Xib to ViewContoller

Tags: xcode, swift

I have a Xib file with a button.  I want to segue to another view controller when the button is clicked.  I've created a segue between the view controllers in StoryBoard and created an identifier, but can't seem to call it programatically.

```
@IBAction func buttonAction(sender: UIButton)
{
 self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SegueToPostDetail", sender: sender)
}
```

Xcode error is "....has no member 'performSequeWithIdentifier'

Thanks!

Comment: did you name the segue in storyboard ?

Comment: Yes I did.  I've read you can't connect a Xib to the storyboard to create a segue, so I've connected the two view controllers via the storyboard.  Named the Indentifier, and now I'm simply trying to call the segue programmatically when I click a button on the Xib.  I can't call performSegueWithIdentifier for some reason.  Says the member doesn't exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't call performSegueWithIdentifier in a Xib class, only in a UIViewController class. So you have 2 solutions:

1. Have the button in the UIViewController and when the button is clicked to call performSegueWithIdentifier.
2. Create a delegate in Xib class and UIViewController class implements that delegate protocol. [How do I set up a simple delegate to communicate between two view controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168919/how-do-i-set-up-a-simple-delegate-to-communicate-between-two-view-controllers)

Comment: Now it makes sense why I can't call performSegueWithIdentifier.  Thanks!