# Swift - instantiate From Nib always return UIViewController type instead dynamic type

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller

I want to load `UIViewController` from nib, and return dynamic type of it.
I tried few functions that i have found, but always the return type in `UIViewController`.
I checked twice that my nib name is equal to the class name `AlertVC`.
I set the file's owner of the nib to be `AlertVC` as well.

The function i use to load from nib:

```
extension UIViewController {
class func loadMeFromXib<T: UIViewController>(_ senderVC:UIViewController, prepareForVC:((T) -> T?)? = nil) {
        var viewController:T = T.instantiateFromNib()
        // viewController type is UIViewController instead AlertVC
    }

    static func instantiateFromNib() -> Self {
        func instantiateFromNib<T: UIViewController>(_ viewType: T.Type) -> T {
            return T.init(nibName: String(describing: T.self), bundle: nil)
        }

        return instantiateFromNib(self)
    }
}
```

Also tried:

```
class func loadMeFromNib<T: UIViewController>() -> T {
    return T(nibName: String(describing: self), bundle: nil)
}
```

But i same result always - UIViewController.

Use it like this:

```
AlertVC.loadMeFromXib(senderVC!)
```

I also got a debugger error: `use of undeclared type 'T'`

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue.  As described in this post:
[Perform a segue from an Xib to ViewContoller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35582099/perform-a-segue-from-an-xib-to-viewcontoller)

> You can't call performSegueWithIdentifier in a Xib class, only in a
>   UIViewController class.

I ended up:

> Creating a delegate in Xib class and UIViewController class implements
>   that delegate protocol.