# Accessing Property from another NSObjectClass

Tags: objective-c, nsobject

I am using 2 nsobject class ,

First nsobject class some property and it holds some values.
In Second NSObject class i want to access the first nsobject class properties.
I have tried little bit  ,it showing null values
Here is my code
**My First NSObject class**
**FieldData.M**

```
-(instancetype)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictFieldData
{
if (self = [super init]) {

    ///set the field id
    self.fieldId = [[dictFieldData objectForKey:@"f_id"]intValue];
    self.display = [[dictFieldData objectForKey:@"f_display"]boolValue];
    self.fieldLength = [[dictFieldData objectForKey:@"f_length"]intValue];
    self.mandatory = [[dictFieldData objectForKey:@"f_mandatary"]boolValue];
    self.strFieldLabel = [dictFieldData objectForKey:@"f_label"];

    NSString *strFieldAttrib = [dictFieldData objectForKey:@"f_attribute"];
    if ([strFieldAttrib.lowercaseString isEqualToString:@"alpha"]) {

        self.fieldAttribute = FieldAttributeAlpha;
    }
    else if ([strFieldAttrib.lowercaseString isEqualToString:@"numeric"]) {

        self.fieldAttribute = FieldAttributeNumeric;
    }
    else if ([strFieldAttrib.lowercaseString isEqualToString:@"alpha_numeric"]) {

        self.fieldAttribute = FieldAttributeAlphaNumeric;
    }

    }return self;
    }
```

****Second NSObjectClass**
SiteData.m**

```
-(instancetype)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictSiteData
{

self.fieldData = [FieldData new];

if (self = [super init]) {


    self.siteId = [[dictSiteData objectForKey:@"s_id"]intValue];

    self.siteName = [dictSiteData objectForKey:@"site_name"];

    NSLog(@"%d",self.fieldData.fieldId);





}

return self;
}
```

Please anyone helpme to do this 
Please what i am doing wrong 
Thanks in Advance !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please write this code in `Appdelegate` declare this property.
After that `SetValue` your Dictionary Data

```
@property(strong,nonatomic)NSDictionary * dictFieldData;
```

Write this code **My First NSObject class FieldData.M**
Create object in `ViewdidLoad`

```
 AppDelegate *appdelegate ((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]);


///set the field id
self.fieldId = [[appdelegate.dictFieldData SetValue:(NSString*) objectForKey:@"f_id"]intValue];

///Get the field id
self.siteId = [[appdelegate.dictSiteData Valueforkey:@"s_id"]intValue];

NSLog(@"%d",appdelegate.dictSiteData);
```

Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168919/how-do-i-set-up-a-simple-delegate-to-communicate-between-two-view-controllers) answer for Accessing Property from another NSObjectClass

Comment: @thnaks ,Himanshu Patel , i want to access the property in second nsobject clss only ,how can i do that please help me

Comment: @thanks Himanshu Patel , working fine ,one more thing  User *userData = [[User alloc]initWithDictionary:userProfileData];

Comment: User *userData = [[User alloc]initWithDictionary:userProfileData];   AZCAppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
                        delegate.userProfiels = userData;

Comment: User *userData = [[User alloc]initWithDictionary:userProfileData]; AZCAppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]; delegate.userProfiels = userData;   this delegate.userProfiles has one array ,that contains nsobejct ,how can i access that nsobject property

Comment: Sorry i didnt downvote it , i just put a tick mark only , i dont have that much reputation

Answer (score 0):

`[FieldData new]` will by default invoke the `init` method, not the `initWithDictionary` one. Unless you've defined `init` to set values for your property it will default to `nil`. You probably need to create your object using `[[FieldData alloc] initWithDictionary:...]` (or `[FieldData newWithDictionary:...]` if you've defined that method). HTH

Comment: i have used still it is showing null values .Plesae anyone helpme

Comment: @AgalSivamanoj - Edit your question and show the interface for `FieldData`, all it's `init` and `new` members, and the revised `SiteData` code which creates the `FieldData` instance.