# if don't use protocol and Block How to update a string ( type NSString) in Objective-C

Tags: ios, nsstring

For Example :
I have two ViewController,   A  and  B ,  A have 
`@Property(copy,nonatomic)NSString *test;`
 if A  push to B   How can update test of A, I have see some answer about Double **  and point.but I don‘t know 。Thank you！

Comment: using `DelegatePattern` is one possibility have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6169104/1390857

Comment: What have u tried ??? Heard of Protocols, Unwind segues ???

Comment: why can't you use protocol or block?

Answer (score 1):

You can use singleton class for that. 
Use AppDelegate for that.

Make a NSString property in AppDelegate and update the value of this NSString from AppDelegate when you will move from A to B.

In viewWillAppear() of A assign the value of NSString from AppDelegate to that in A(test)

**In AppDelegate.h**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *value;
```

**In ViewController A**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"


-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

    self.test = appDelegate.value;

}
```

When push to ViewController B:

**You can assign new value to AppDelegate NSString as:**

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

appDelegate.value = @"YOUR NEW VALUE";
```