# How to interrupt a Viewcontroller when another class is finished processing required data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, nsobject

I have two classes, one view controller an another NSObject class that performs async processes, once its done I want to interrupt the view controller similar to what a button does as IBAction, to update UI. I wanted to keep this functionality in modularized for better use in later stages. Is there a way to do this on Objective-c?

CircleDetectionViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CameraController.h"



@interface CircleDetectionViewController : UIViewController <MyDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *screenPreview;

@end
```

CircleViewController.mm:

```
@interface CircleDetectionViewController () <CvVideoCameraDelegate>

@end

@implementation CircleDetectionViewController
CvVideoCamera *camera;
//code
@end
```

CameraController.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import "CircleDetectionViewController.h"

@protocol MyDelegate <NSObject>

-(void) updateUI;
@end

@interface CameraController : NSObject <MyDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVCaptureDevice *inputDevice;
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVCaptureSession *session;
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVCaptureStillImageOutput *photoOutput;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <MyDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

CameraController.m:

```
#import "CameraController.h"
#import "FlashHelper.h"
#import "ImageProcessor.h"

@implementation CameraController
@synthesize delegate;
FlashHelper *Flash;
ImageProcessor *IMGProcessor;
int shootCounter;
int NUMSHOTS = 2;

-(id)init{
//code 
}
```

For some reason the code says "No type or protocol named MyDelegate"
Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: use delegates or callbacks / completion blocks. That should be terms you can google easily and use after you understood them.

Comment: Perfect time for Delegate pattern! https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html

Comment: My view controller already has a delegate for openCV used, can i still use my own custom delegate?

Answer (score -1):

In NSObject class create a delegate:

```
@protocol MyDelegate <NSObject>

-(void) updateUI;
@end
```

and declare a property of delegate

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <MyDelegate> delegate;
```

In viewcontroller class invoke the delegate class

NSObject class `obj.delegate = self;`
and implement the delegate method.

Always update your UI from Main Thread.

To get the main thread use this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   // call your delegate method or update UI here
});
```

For details for delegate methods check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168919/how-do-i-set-up-a-simple-delegate-to-communicate-between-two-view-controllers).

Comment: The problem I have with delegates is that my view controller already has a delegate in use the openCV camera one, is there a way to use two delegates?

Comment: You can invoke multiple delegates in one view controller like UIViewController <UIAccelerometerDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate>. Also, you can use NSNotificationCenter to achieve the same purpose.