# Callback on CNContactViewController

Tags: ios, swift, cncontactviewcontroller

How to get a callBack when user successfully saves or dismiss the `CNContactViewController`

```
func addContact(contactDetails: ContactDetails) {
    let store = CNContactStore()
    let contact = CNMutableContact()
    let comp = contactDetails.name.components(separatedBy: " ")
    contact.givenName = comp.first ?? ""
    contact.familyName = comp.count > 1 ? comp[1] : ""
    let homePhone = CNLabeledValue(label: CNLabelHome, value: CNPhoneNumber(stringValue :contactDetails.phone ))
    contact.phoneNumbers = [homePhone]
    let workEmail = CNLabeledValue(label:CNLabelWork, value:contactDetails.email as NSString)
    contact.emailAddresses = [workEmail]
    let controller = CNContactViewController(forUnknownContact : contact)// .viewControllerForUnknownContact(contact)
    controller.contactStore = store
    controller.delegate = self
    //self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a delegate / protocol for communicate between controllers. Check below link for simple code example;

[Simple Protocol Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168919/how-do-i-set-up-a-simple-delegate-to-communicate-between-two-view-controllers)

Comment: But how I can do it in this scenario as this is done on `CNContactViewController`

Comment: Create a protocol function in your firstViewController. Then in your contactViewController call this function where you tap dismiss button etc..