# UIDropInteractionDelegate not being called

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `DropAreaViewController` in my app. Inside this controller I run the following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIDropInteraction *interaction = [[UIDropInteraction alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
    [self.view addInteraction:interaction];
}

- (BOOL)dropInteraction:(UIDropInteraction *)dropInteraction canHandleSession:(nonnull id<UIDropSession>)session {
    NSLog(@"canHandleSession called");
    return true;
}

- (UIDropProposal *)dropInteraction:(UIDropInteraction *)dropInteraction sessionDidUpdate:(nonnull id<UIDropSession>)session {
    NSLog(@"sessionDidUpdate");
    if (session.localDragSession != nil) {
        NSLog(@"is localDragSession");
        return [[UITableViewDropProposal alloc] initWithDropOperation:UIDropOperationMove intent:UITableViewDropIntentInsertAtDestinationIndexPath];
    } else {
        return [[UITableViewDropProposal alloc] initWithDropOperation:UIDropOperationCancel];
    }
}

- (void)dropInteraction:(UIDropInteraction *)interaction performDrop:(id<UIDropSession>)session {
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

Now, in another viewcontroller I add this controller:

```
DropAreaViewController *davc = [[DropAreaViewController alloc] init];
davc.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
[self.view addSubview:davc.view];
```

None of the drops are being registered though. I get not logs at all when I hover a drop on top of the square. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you declare delegate in interactionviewcontroller?

Comment: @EmreÖnder What exactly do you mean?

Comment: Check for delegate and protocol functions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168919/how-do-i-set-up-a-simple-delegate-to-communicate-between-two-view-controllers

Comment: `UIDropInteraction` is provided by UIKit. So there's no need for what you are suggesting.

Comment: Ok sorry then. I didn't know.

Comment: Same here. This API is the worse.