# Master detail project - remove master cell from detail

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've a master detail project, when I click on a cell in the master I can see the detail with the number of row with this code in the prepareForSegue:

```
DetailViewController *controller = (DetailViewController *)[[segue destinationViewController] topViewController];
[controller setDetailItem:indexPath.row];
```

Now in the detail I have a button too, when I click I want to remove the cell at the master's index saved in the detailItem of DetailViewController.

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: On "Remove" button press, remove the object from the master's array and navigate or pop the detailVC and reload the master's table data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can do it by implementing simple delegate pattern, you can find answer here:

[How do I set up a simple delegate to communicate between two view controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168919/how-do-i-set-up-a-simple-delegate-to-communicate-between-two-view-controllers)
(just in case: Master – root view controller, details - child)