# swift pass values from one subviecontroller to mainviewcontroller in storyboard

Tags: delegates, storyboard, segue, swift5, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a ViewControlScene (ViewController-A) in Storyboard which has a SegmentControl at top and "ListCount Label" at the bottom. There was a view in between area which was embedded to another ViewControlScene (ViewController-B) via segue in Storyboard.
The ViewController-B has a tableview with custom cell.
Now I need to get the data modified in the ViewController-B from it to ViewController-A to display it in the "ListCount Label".

Please refer the attached image for more details.[image]

Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5210535/643383) and [How do I set up a simple delegate to communicate between two view controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6168919/643383)

Comment: Thanks for providing me useful links, I referred it and worked it out.