# Separate Delegate and Controller

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, model-view-controller, delegates, controller

As many other developers new to Cocoa, I struggle with delegate and controller concept. I get the basics, but one thing bugs me. Practically every explanation says that "usually" or "in simple cases" (which are the only ones they give as examples) controller and delegate tend to be the same object.
That leads to a question: when would you want to separate controller and delegate for the same interface object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two general cases when using a separate class for your delegate is needed are

1. When you need to perform unrelated actions in response to the same delegate message, or
2. When you would like to share the logic of the delegate among multiple views or controllers.

An example of the first situation would be a page with two unrelated tables. Each `UITableView` would need its own delegate, so using the controller as the delegate would require an ugly `if` statement in each delegate method; defining and using separate delegates is clearly preferred in this case.

An example of the second situation would be a group of similar pages that show DB data from tables of similar structure. Pages themselves are sufficiently dissimilar, so you cannot reuse the controller in its entirety. If you choose to put the delegate into the controller, most of the logic behind the table view's data source would be identical. You can put the code into a shared delegate implementation, and have each controller instantiate that delegate with the configuration parameters specific to the table associated with this controller.

One note to keep in mind when using another object besides the controller as your delegate: the controller should retain / keep a strong reference to the delegate, since the view will only keep a weak / assign reference to it.  See [property "assign" and "retain" for delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176261/property-assign-and-retain-for-delegate) for more information on this.