# custom delegate in objective c

Tags: objective-c, delegates

i've done a class like this:

```
testClass <UIAccelerometerDelegate>
```

and i implement the methods of delegate.

Then in other class where i want this delegate i've done:

```
testClass *t = [[testClass alloc]init];
UIAccelerometer *a = [UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer];
[a setDelegate: t];
```

and in dealloc i release t.

It works, but is this the right way to write a general delegate?

Answer (score 0):

In general that is right, but you need to be careful when deciding to `retain` or `assign` the delegate to avoid circular references. I have been bit by this before. Here is a good post talking about it and some nuances to be aware of: [Why are Objective-C delegates usually given the property assign instead of retain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918698/why-are-objective-c-delegates-usually-given-the-property-assign-instead-of-retain)

Comment: `UIAccelerometer` is apple's class, so the OP doesn't have to worry about any delegate retain/release issues. This answer has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Why the down vote? Did you read the whole question? He is asking if in **GENERAL** that is the right way to use delegates, not just with the `UIAccelerometer` class. If he is releasing it in dealloc, he is retaining it, therefore it is relevant. Read the whole question next time...

Comment: He was asking how to set delegates for other objects, not how to deal with delegates properties of his own objects. The OP's `testClass` is an iVar of his class, so it must be retained and released.

Answer (score 0):

That is one way to write a delegate. An easier way would be to implement the delegate methods in the class in which you created your `testClass` instance and set the `UIAccelerometer` delegate property to `self`.

Also, just a consistency note, it's proper for class names to start with a capitalized letter, so your class should be called `TestClass`.

---

Also, you do need to set the `UIAccelerometer` delegate property to `nil` when you deallocate the delegate object.