# Recommended way to declare delegate properties with ARC

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, delegates, automatic-ref-counting

I used to declare all delegate properties as

```
@property (assign) id<FooDelegate> delegate;
```

I was under the impression that all assign properties should now be weak pointers, is this correct?
If I try to declare as:

```
@property (weak) id<FooDelegate> delegate;
```

I get an error while trying to @synthesize (autogenerated weak properties are not supported).

What's the best practice in this case?

Comment: This is a good question and the answers are not very conclusive. I would have thought to use weak but the Apple frameworks use assign (see UIPageViewController which is only available on iOS5+).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use `__unsafe_unretained` instead `weak` for ARC projects targeting iOS 4 and 5. The only difference is that `weak` nils the pointer when deallocated, and it's only supported in iOS 5.

Your other question is answered in [Why are Objective-C delegates usually given the property assign instead of retain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918698/why-are-objective-c-delegates-usually-given-the-property-assign-instead-of-retain/918732#918732).

Comment: However, I am compiling it for iOS 5, so I guess it should work... :-?

Comment: That's weird, if your "Deployment Target" is 5.0 it should work with just (weak).

Answer (score 23):

Xcode 4 **Refactor** > **Convert to Objective-C ARC** transforms:

```
@interface XYZ : NSObject
{
    id delegate;
}
@property (assign) id delegate;
...
@synthesize delegate;
```

into:

```
@interface XYZ : NSObject
{
    id __unsafe_unretained delegate;
}
@property (unsafe_unretained) id delegate;
...
@synthesize delegate;
```

If I remember correctly it is also mentioned in WWDC 2011 video about ARC.

Comment: I'll check out the video again.

Comment: Why not use `weak` instead?

Comment: This was relevant *2* years ago, when a younger clang and vintage iOS SDKs populated the Earth.