# My delegate doesn't work

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates

I'm working on an app that has a shopping cart. When I add a product in my shopping cart, my button segues to a table view controller modally. Then when I select a row, the modal view controller should be dismissed. I tried to implement this using my delegate. Here's my code:

(irrelevant code omitted)

ItemsTableViewController (the list of products to choose from)

```
//the header file
@class ItemsTableViewController;

@protocol ItemsTableViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void) itemsTableViewController: (ItemsTableViewController *)sender
                 didSelectProduct: (Product *) aProduct;

@end

@interface ItemsTableViewController : CoreDataTableViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIManagedDocument *itemDatabase;

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <ItemsTableViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

//snippets from the implementation

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    Product *item = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    [self.delegate itemsTableViewController:self didSelectProduct:item];
    NSLog(@"DID SELECT ROW AT index %d with name %@", indexPath.row, item.name);

}
```

//here's my shopping cart, the ItemsTableViewController delegate

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Show Products List"]){
        ItemsTableViewController *itemsTVC = (ItemsTableViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        itemsTVC.delegate = self;

    }
}
- (void) itemsTableViewController:(ItemsTableViewController *)sender didSelectProduct:(Product *)aProduct{
    //adds the product in the shopping cart
    [self.shoppingCart addObject:aProduct];
    [self.products reloadData];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    NSLog(@"from the delegate got product %@", aProduct.name);
}
```

Comment: What actually happens when you run it?  Where else have you put calls to `NSLog` (or breakpoints) to make sure your variables are assigned properly and your methods are getting called (or not called)?  What is the output from your logging?

Comment: It logs that a row was selected and the item is identified but from the delegate's part it doesn't log     NSLog(@"from the delegate got product %@", aProduct.name);

Comment: is there a reason your delegate is weak?

Comment: all delegates are supposed to be weak @rokjarc

Comment: shouldn't it be __unsafe_unretained for use with ARC? ie: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7753841/recommended-way-to-declare-delegate-properties-with-arc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The destination of your segue is a UINavigationController, not an ItemsTableViewController.  Perhaps you put your ItemsTableViewController inside a UINavigationController on your storyboard.  Try this:

```
UINavigationController *navController = segue.destinationViewController;
ItemsTableViewController *itemsTVC = (ItemsTableViewController *)navController.topViewController;
itemsTVC.delegate = self;
```

Comment: If setting the delegate to strong didn't fix it, then something else is going on.  Either `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` is being sent to a different instance of `ItemsTableViewController` than the instance you accessed in `prepareForSegue:sender:`, or something is setting the delegate to nil after you set it in `prepareForSegue:sender:`.

Comment: how can I check whether tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: is sent to the right instance?

Comment: but I set the destinationViewController like this:ItemsTableViewController *itemsTVC = (ItemsTableViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        itemsTVC.delegate = self; So I think tableView: didSelectRowAtIndexPath: is being sent to that instnce. How will I check what's setting it nil then?

Comment: You can log `itemsTVC` with the `%p` format, and then log `self` with `%p` in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, and make sure you see the same value.

Comment: You could try setting a breakpoint on `-[ItemsTableViewController setDelegate:]`.

Comment: You could try using a watchpoint.  Put a breakpoint in `-[ItemsTableViewController setDelegate:]`.  Then get the address of the delegate variable with `p/x &self->delegate` or `p/x &self->_delegate` (depending on how you named the instance variable).  It will be something like `0x1030618e0`.  Then you can set a watchpoint with a command like `watch *(id *)0x1030618e0`.

Comment: ok I'll try you're suggestions first. btw, I just realized that I'm inside a tab bar controller. That's my presentingViewController's class when my itemTVC is up modally.

Comment: I got different values for self and itemsTVC --> itemsTVC: 0x8113710, self: 0x81134c0

Comment: What's the output if you use `%@` instead of `%p`?

Comment: here's the output using %@: itemsTVC: <UINavigationController: 0x6b4e860>, self: <ItemsTableViewController: 0x6b4e5a0>

Comment: seems like itemsTVC is not being casted as an ItemsTableViewController because I also NSLog-ed what segue.destinationViewController is and this is what I got: destinationVC: <UINavigationController: 0x6d76f30>