# Send a Delegate message from UIPopover to Main UIViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, delegates, uitextview, uipopovercontroller

I'm trying to use a Button in my `UIPopover` to create a `UITextView` in my Main `UIViewController` the code I have looks something like this (`PopoverView.h` file):

```
@protocol PopoverDelegate <NSObject> 

- (void)buttonAPressed;

@end

@interface PopoverView : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate> {  //<UITextViewDelegate>

    id <PopoverDelegate> delegate;
    BOOL sendDelegateMessages;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) id delegate;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL sendDelegateMessages;
@end
```

Then in my `PopoverView.m` file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

UIButton * addTB1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
addTB1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50);
[addTB1 setTitle:@"Textbox One" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:addTB1];    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
[addTB1 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAPressed) 
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

- (void)buttonAPressed
{
    NSLog(@"tapped button one");

    if (sendDelegateMessages)
        [delegate buttonAPressed];
}
```

And also in my `MainViewController.m` :

```
- (void)buttonAPressed {

    NSLog(@"Button Pressed");
    UITextView *textfield = [[UITextView alloc] init];
    textfield.frame = CGRectMake(50, 30, 100, 100);
    textfield.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [self.view addSubview:textfield];
}
```

I'm using a delegate protocol to link the popover and the ViewController but I'm stuck on how I get my `BOOL` statement to link the `-(void)buttonAPressed` in the PopoverView and  MainViewController so that when I press the button in the Popover a textview appears in the Main VC. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `MainViewController`, where you create `PopoverView`, be sure to set its `delegate` property otherwise sending messages to `delegate` in `PopoverView` will do nothing.

For example, in `MainViewController.m`:

```
PopoverView *pov = [[PopoverView alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
pov.delegate = self;  // <-- must set this
thePopoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContent...
```

I am not sure why you need the `sendDelegateMessages` variable.  Even with that bool, you must set the `delegate` property so `PopoverView` has an actual object reference to send the messages to.

If you want to make sure the `delegate` object has implemented the method you're about to call, you can do this instead:

```
if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(buttonAPressed)])
    [delegate buttonAPressed];
```

Also, the `delegate` property should be declared using `assign` (or `weak` if using ARC) instead of `retain` (see [Why use weak pointer for delegation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449040/why-use-weak-pointer-for-delegation) for an explanation):

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<PopoverDelegate> delegate;
```

Another thing is if you're not using ARC, you need to add `[textfield release];` at the end of the `buttonAPressed` method in `MainViewController` to avoid a memory leak.

Comment: That's definitely fixed it thanks so much! And thanks for the tips as well. Will stop me from making more mistakes.