# Pass data back from PopOver to Viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

I have a popoverview with a table, and I want to pass back some data when I click on a cell, but I don't know how to do...

Comment: What you need to send ? array or what ??

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8884522/send-a-delegate-message-from-uipopover-to-main-uiviewcontroller it may help you..

Comment: I need sent a NSUrl...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Familiarize yourself with the delegate pattern. 
Define a method in a protocol for passing down the data. 
Set the view controller as the popover controller's delegate. The view controller should implement the protocol. 
In the popover controller pass this data when the button is pressed. 
In the view controller process this data accordingly.

Comment: I made it all, ma I don't know how can I set he view controller as the popover controller's delegate... can you explain me?

Comment: From the view controller call `popopverController.delegate = self;` after creating the popover controller before presenting it.

Comment: OK, thank you, I've done It with this code:
    `- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"popover"])
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",[segue destinationViewController]);
        self.popSegue = (UIStoryboardPopoverSegue*)segue;
        
        [[segue destinationViewController] setDelegate:self];
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Dude you can try delegates if the table view is in a different class or if table view is in the same class just see didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

Writing a delegate:

In .h file of popover table class:

```
@protocol PopOverSelectionDelegate;
@property (nonatomic,weak) id <PopOverSelectionDelegate> delegate;
@protocol PopOverSelectionDelegate 

@optional

- (void)popOverItemSelected:(NSString *)selectedItem;

@end
```

In .m file

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.delegate popOverItemSelected: [yourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}
```