# Objective-C: Delegate is nil in modal in navigation controller

Tags: objective-c, delegates, uinavigationcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I've got a ViewController inside a navigation controller that needs to present a modal.

The ViewController has this as its header:

```
@interface ViewController : BaseViewController<AuthenticateDelegate>
```

and in the IBAction that presents the modal:

```
 AuthenticationController *authVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AuthControllerView"];
        authVC.delegate = self;
        [self presentModalViewController:authVC animated:YES];
```

The AuthenticationController has this in its .h file:

```
@interface AuthenticationController: BaseViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <AuthenticateDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

As you can see, I have assigned "self" (the ViewController) as the delegate to the AuthenticationController, but for some reason, the delegate is  in:

```
- (IBAction)SubmitAuthentication:(id)sender;
{
    [self.delegate validateUser:lblUsername.text :lblPassword.text];

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you must create delegate property as below.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) id <AuthenticateDelegate> delegate;
```

Comment: delegates usually should be saved to weak properties http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449040/why-use-weak-pointer-for-delegation