# iOS - Set Model class to be delegate of another Model class

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, model, delegates

I have a CLLocationManager singleton which implements a protocol, so I can tell another model class (ServerConnection) that an updated location of the user has been found.

In my AppDelegate in the method, didFinishLaunching, I write

```
ServerConnection* serverConnection = [[ServerConnection alloc] init];
[LocationManager sharedLocationSingleton].delegate = serverConnection;
[[LocationManager sharedLocationSingleton] getUsersLocation];
```

This doesn't work and the delegate method in my ServerConnection class isn't called. However, if I try having my AppDelegate class be the listener, as in the following line, it works fine.

```
// self refers to AppDelegate
[LocationManager sharedLocationSingleton].delegate = self;
```

Here, my AppDelegate implements the required delegate method and the method is called when the user's location is updated, as it should.

Why is my above method failing, where I try to set the delegate to be serverConnection?

Tutorials online usually point to using a UIViewController or the AppDelegate as the "listener", but in my case, I want a separate model class to be the listener. How do I do that?

Below is my LocationManager singleton class with the protocol

```
@class LocationManager;

@protocol LocationManagerDelegate <NSObject>
@required
-(void)LocationManagerUpdated:(LocationManager*) locationManager
                  withValue:(CLLocation*) location;
@end

@interface LocationManager : NSObject <CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager* locationManager;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocation* location;
@property (weak, nonatomic) id <LocationManagerDelegate> delegate;

+(LocationManager*)sharedLocationSingleton;
-(void) getUsersLocation;

@end
```

My header file for Server connection is.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "LocationManager.h"

@interface ServerConnection : NSObject <LocationManagerDelegate>
@end
```

This works when AppDelegate is set to be the listener, but not my model object ServerConnection. How do I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: what is `ServerConnection` interface definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be no problem in doing what you are trying to do (i.e., having a non-controller class instance to act as a delegate).

> This works when AppDelegate is set to be the listener, but not my model object ServerConnection.

Does your `ServerConnection` class implement the `LocationManagerDelegate` protocol? (I mean implement as opposed to just declare it in its interface).

Check the `LocationManager` method in charge for calling the delegate method (`LocationManagerUpdated:`) and add there a `NSLog` trace to check that the delegate object is correctly set when you try and send it the message.

EDIT:

```
ServerConnection* serverConnection = [[ServerConnection alloc] init];
[LocationManager sharedLocationSingleton].delegate = serverConnection;
[[LocationManager sharedLocationSingleton] getUsersLocation];
```

after you comment, it is clear that the issue stems from instantiating `serverConnection` in a stack variable and not in a property.

Your approach of making the `delegate` property a strong property is not correct since [it leads to retain cycles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449040/why-use-weak-pointer-for-delegation). What you need to do is defining a `strong` `serverConnection` property in the class that executes the code I pasted above (the app delegate?).

If you don't mind my being rash, if you define the delegate as a strong property, what you are doing is fixing a bug by adding a second bug that hides the first one.

Comment: Thanks! Fixed this by changing my property declaration of the delegate from weak to strong

Comment: setting a delegate as a strong property is recipe for disaster, since it will cause a cyclic dependency:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449040/why-use-weak-pointer-for-delegation

Answer (score -1):

It looks like `serverConnection` is not retained anywhere and because `delegate` property is specified as `weak`, it is released and set to nil.

Check `getUsersLocation` method and see if delegate is nil at the moment you are trying to call `LocationManagerUpdated:withValue:`

Comment: Thanks! I fixed it by making the delegate property strong instead of weak

Comment: You should not make delegate property strong. I would suggest to think about other solution. The question is, why don't you retain `serverConnection` anywhere. Maybe you don't need this `delegate` property and just make `serverConnection` as private property of your `LocationManager`