# Difference between different property declaration in the delegate case

Tags: ios, objective-c

Can anyone tell me what is the difference among three property of delegation. I searched in google but did not get any satisfactory answer.
Please also tell me which is the best option and why?

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) id <GameAddViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <GameAddViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <GameAddViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is same as with [`strong`, `weak` and `assign`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8927727/objective-c-arc-strong-vs-retain-and-weak-vs-assign) specifiers.

Points to be noted : Any object never retains the delegate. Hence `strong` and `retain` should not be used.

`weak` and `assign` are allowed or even you can go with `unsafe_unretained`.

[Why not to use `retain`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918698/why-are-objective-c-delegates-usually-given-the-property-assign-instead-of-retai)

[Why use `weak` or `assign`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449040/why-use-weak-pointer-for-delegation)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Anoop. can you tell me in which case I have to use assign or weak

Comment: Mostly you use `weak` with delegates. As `assign` simply points to the same value and is frequently used with primitive data types, and delegates aren't.

Answer (score 2):

**Weak**

> weak applies to the delegate object (which has reference counts and
>   all the stuff), but weak references don't increase refcount. But once
>   the delegate object is deallocated (from anywhere in the code), any
>   weak reference to that object is set to nil. This is extremely useful,
>   because if you use only strong and weak references, you can't end up
>   with an invalid pointer (pointer to an already deallocated object).

**Assign**

> assign is usually used for ints, floats and other non-object types.
>   You can of course assign an object reference to such a variable, but
>   if the object is deallocated, you will still have a pointer to it's
>   memory (which is garbage now, and will hurt you when you use it).

**Strong**

> Strong will keep the object in the heap until it don't point to it
>   anymore. In other words " I'am the owner, you cannot dealloc this
>   before i'm fine with that same as retain" You use strong only if you
>   need to retain the object.

In case of delegation, weak preferred

Answer (score 0):

You generally want to assign delegates rather than retain them, in order to avoid circular retain counts where object A retains object B and object B retains object A. (You might see this referred to as keeping a "weak reference" to the delegate.) For example, consider the following common pattern:

```
-(void)someMethod {
self.utilityObject = [[[Bar alloc] init] autorelease];
self.utilityObject.delegate = self;
[self.utilityObject doSomeWork];
}
```

if the `utilityObject` and `delegate` properties are both declared using retain, then self now retains `self.utilityObject` and `self.utilityObjec`t retains self.

[Also see this detailed answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918698/why-are-objective-c-delegates-usually-given-the-property-assign-instead-of-retai/918732#918732)