# Objective C delegates and protocols

Tags: delegates, protocols

**Why do we need to use id type for creating delegate object for protocols in Objective C? I couldn't find proper answer from google**

Answer (score 0):

Because a delegate can be implemented by any type of object.
Ex : `UIViewController`, `UIView`, `NSObject` class can all implement the same protocol, so the delegate can't know the type, so it's set to `id`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. also why we are using **weak** type for **id** object instead of **strong** type?

Comment: Take a look at this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449040/why-use-weak-pointer-for-delegation.  And can you mark my answer as accepted if it's ok for you.