# Delegates and their retain rule

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a modal view controller that takes another UIViewController as delegate.

My doubt is about handling the delegate object in the modal view controller. Should I assign it or retain it in the modal view controller? Is there any convention to handle delegates in cocoa?

If I assign it, who will release the UIViewController and if I retain it, I have to release that reference in the ModalViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delegates are typically assigned in Cocoa.

Check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918698/why-are-objective-c-delegates-usually-given-the-property-assign-instead-of-retai), it's answered beautifully.