# Delegates between class and viewController.m

Tags: objective-c, ios, delegates

I have the `PGMidi.h` with the following delegate

```
@protocol PGMidiSourceDelegate
- (void) midiSource:(PGMidiSource*)input midiReceived:(const MIDIPacketList *)packetList;
```

Then in my `viewController.m` I simply want to get an `NSLog` when the delegate is called so

```
@interface viewController () <PGMidiDelegate, PGMidiSourceDelegate>

@end

@implementation viewController;

- (void) midiSource:(PGMidiSource*)midi midiReceived:(const MIDIPacketList *)packetList   
{
  NSLog(@"test");
}
```

I know that the delegate is working because in the `PGMidi` Class I also put

```
- (void) midiSource:(PGMidiSource*)midi midiReceived:(const MIDIPacketList *)packetList  
{
 NSLog(@"test");
}
```

and it works.

But for some reason it is not communicating with the viewController.m. I am also declaring the @PGMidi class in the header. But perhaps I have to import the entire PGMidi.h?

Answer (score 1):

In your PGMidi.h you should actually declare a delegate property, i.e.

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<PGMidiSourceDelegate> delegate;
```

Make sure to `synthesize` that property in your PGMidi.m file. Then, in your PGMidi.m you should be doing this:

```
-(void) midiSource:(PGMidiSource*)midi midiReceived:(const MIDIPacketList *)packetList {
    [delegate midiSource:midi midiReceived:packetList];
}
```

You also need to actually set the view controller as the delegate of your PGMidi object:

```
myPGMidi.delegate = myViewController;
```

Comment: I've always been curious about this; what does `assign` mean? I've read apple docs and other questions but I can't quite grasp its meaning.

Comment: assign represents a weak reference -- in this case, since your view controller is already retained in memory, we do not need to increase the retain count of the object by making it a strong property. In many cases, if you don't use a weak reference in a delegate setup you can create a retain cycle. check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918698/why-are-objective-c-delegates-usually-given-the-property-assign-instead-of-retai

Answer (score 0):

Do you include `@end` to conclude your code `@protocol PGMidiSourceDelegate` in PGMidi.h? Also make sure in viewController.h that you say `@interface viewController : (parentClass) <PGMidiSourceDelegate`. (parentClass) is whatever class viewController inherits from. Basically, either your problem is you forgot the @end or you didn't specify that viewController is a delegate of PGMidi.h.